# What is the difference between a process and a thread?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

What is the technical difference between a process and a thread?

I get the feeling a word like 'process' is overused and there are also hardware and software threads. How about light-weight processes in languages like [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29)? Is there a definitive reason to use one term over the other?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294367/erlang-process-vs-java-thread/32296577#32296577

Comment: It probably warrants saying that each OS has a different idea of what is a 'thread' or 'process'.  Some mainstream OS' don't have a concept of 'thread', there are also some embedded OS' that only have 'threads'.

Comment: TLDR: Sibling "threads" (in most operating systems) share the same virtual address space, the same sockets and open files, all the same resources. "Processes," on the other hand are isolated/protected from one another, and they share nothing except when they explicitly request to share some specific thing. In an OS that has both "processes" and "threads," a process often can be thought of as a container for one or more threads and, for all of the resources that they share.

Answer (score 1764, accepted):

Both processes and threads are independent sequences of execution. The typical difference is that threads (of the same process) run in a shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces.

I'm not sure what "hardware" vs "software" threads you might be referring to. Threads are an operating environment feature, rather than a CPU feature (though the CPU typically has operations that make threads efficient).

Erlang uses the term "process" because it does not expose a shared-memory multiprogramming model. Calling them "threads" would imply that they have shared memory.

Comment: Hardware threads are probably referring to multiple thread contexts within a core (e.g. HyperThreading, SMT, Sun's Niagara/Rock).  This means duplicated register files,extra bits carried around with the instruction through the pipelines,and more complex bypassing/forwarding logic,among other things.

Comment: @greg, one doubt I have in threads. let me consider I have a process A, which got some space in RAM. If the process A creates a thread, the thread also need some space to execute. So will it increase size of the space which is created for process A, or space for thread created somewhere else ? so what is that virtual space process creates ? Please correct me if my question is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK: Creating a new thread allocates at least enough memory for a new stack. This memory is allocated by the OS in process A.

Comment: This answer seems wrong. If both processes and threads were independent sequences of execution, then a process that contained two threads would have to have three sequences of execution, and that can't be right. Only a thread is a sequence of execution -- a process is a container that can hold one or more sequences of execution.

Comment: Please define "sequences of execution".  What does that EXACTLY mean in the context of code?  Is that a function?  Is that something totally different than what I'm assuming here?  It's not enough for me to understand that sentence alone.

Comment: @WTF: To use a terrible analogy, if one "sequence of execution" is a spider crawling from one instruction to another following what your source code says (loops, if statements, function calls, etc), then two sequences of execution is two spiders each doing their own thing. In terms of CPUs, each sequence of execution has its own set of registers which includes both data registers as well as instruction pointer.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks.  I guess my hang-up is I thought a sequence of execution is a function ...like a function in code

Comment: "Hardware threads" are threads that are given individual hardware resources (a separate core, processor, or hyperthread). "Software threads" are threads that have to compete for the same processing power.

Comment: Erlang's "process" is a misnomer IMO. Should have used a different word. Golang went with "goroutines" which is nice because it's a new unique word.

Comment: Apologies if this has already been covered, the comments here are a lot of reading, I would just like to point out that "hardware threads" (due to the lack of knowledge in the answer) are CPU Threads (used in reference to multi-core, or multi-thread CPUs - Dual Core, Duo Core(difference in these two CPU references is 2 cores 2 threads(Dual), vs 1 core 2 threads(Duo)))

Comment: Reading this answer, is threading therefore possible on single processor architectures?

Comment: @p1100i the linke to "shortcuts and aliases" in your profile is 404

Comment: @DeanP  multiple threads have been in use on single processor architectures for at least 50 years.  They do not execute simultaneously on such an architecture; the CPU switches between them.

Comment: @David Schwartz That's my understanding too, which is why we say "a process has at least a single thread of execution", which wouldn't be the case if processes and threads are independent sequences of execution. As you said, a process is a container for at least one thread of execution.

Answer (score 984):

This information was found on Microsoft Learn here: [**About Processes and Threads**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> **Process**
> Each *process* provides the resources needed to execute a program. A process has a virtual address space, executable code, open handles to system objects, a security context, a unique process identifier, environment variables, a priority class, minimum and maximum working set sizes, and at least one thread of execution. Each process is started with a single thread, often called the *primary thread*, but can create additional threads from any of its threads.
>
> **Thread**
> A *thread* is an entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources. In addition, each thread maintains exception handlers, a scheduling priority, thread local storage, a unique thread identifier, and a set of structures the system will use to save the thread context until it is scheduled. The *thread context* includes the thread's set of machine registers, the kernel stack, a thread environment block, and a user stack in the address space of the thread's process. Threads can also have their own security context, which can be used for impersonating clients.
>
> Microsoft Windows supports *preemptive multitasking*, which creates the effect of simultaneous execution of multiple threads from multiple processes. On a multiprocessor computer, the system can simultaneously execute as many threads as there are processors on the computer.

Comment: lets add thread mostly using by programmer in virtual machine's memory environment. but process domain is operating system.

Comment: For people who want to know why cant you format a floppy at the same time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708707/unexplain-comment-of-differences-between-thread-and-processes

Comment: why every process always need at least 1 thread? theoretically, what would happen if a process had 0 threads?

Comment: @LuisVasconcellos - If there were no threads, then the process wouldn't do anything. The process would only be some code and program state loaded into memory. It's not much use. It'd be like having a road with no vehicles travelling along it.

Comment: This answer is way better than the accepted answer because it talks about the _ideal_ of processes and threads:  They should be separate things with separate concerns.    The fact is, most operating systems have history that goes back farther than the invention of threads, and consequently, in most operating systems, those concerns are still somewhat entangled, even if they are slowly improving over time.

Comment: with the utmost respect sir this answer is a reference to those who already know, and does not help those who don't know. it reads much like a wikipedia entry.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon With every explanation one gives, you have to take your reader from one level of understanding to the next level. Unfortunately, I can't tailor the answer to every reader and so have to assume a level of knowledge. For those who don't know, they can make further searches of terms I use they don't understand, can't they, until they reach a base point they do understand. I was going to suggest you offer your own answer, but am happy to see you already have.

Comment: I am not checking only the answers, but also the novel along the comments. I am loving this!

Answer (score 350):

I copied this info from the [**Knowledge Quest! blog**](http://web.archive.org/web/20100807021758/http://kquest.co.cc/2010/03/program-process-task-thread):

> **Process:**
>
> - An executing instance of a program is called a process.
> - Some operating systems use the term ‘task‘ to refer to  a program that is being executed.
> - A process is always stored in the main memory also termed as the primary memory or random access memory.
> - Therefore, a process is termed as an active entity. It disappears if the machine is rebooted.
> - Several process may be associated with a same program.
> - On a multiprocessor system, multiple processes can be executed in parallel.
> - On a uni-processor system, though true parallelism is not achieved, a process scheduling algorithm is applied and the processor is
>   scheduled to execute each process one at a time yielding  an illusion
>   of concurrency.
> - **Example:** Executing multiple instances of the ‘Calculator’ program. Each of the instances are termed as a process.
>
> **Thread:**
>
> - A thread is a subset of the process.
> - It is termed as a ‘lightweight process’, since it is similar to a real process but executes within the context of a process and shares
>   the same resources allotted to the process by the kernel.
> - Usually, a process has only one thread of control – one set of machine instructions executing at a time.
> - A process may also be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.
> - Multiple threads of control can exploit the true parallelism possible on multiprocessor systems.
> - On a uni-processor system, a thread scheduling algorithm is applied and the processor is scheduled to run each thread one at a time.
> - All the threads running within a process share the same address space, file descriptors, stack and other process related attributes.
> - Since the threads of a process share the same memory, synchronizing the access to the shared data within the process gains unprecedented
>   importance.

Comment: Kumar: From my knowledge, threads do not share the same stack. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to run different code on each of them.

Comment: Yup I think @MihaiNeacsu is right. Threads share "code, data and files" and have their own "registers and stack". Slide from my OS course: http://i.imgur.com/Iq1Qprv.png

Comment: This is quite useful, as it expands on what threads and processes are and how they relate to each other. I'd suggest adding an example of a Thread, especially since there's one for a Process. Good stuff!

Comment: @Kumar Please correct the answer regarding the stack sharing part of the threads. It creates confusion.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer but actually as @Mihai Neacsu stated threads share other segments as data,code & heap as well but they didn't share their call stack, may be you mean threads can access other threads stack not sharing it.if they share stack taking care of objects synchronization would be more of a hell process.

Comment: @Rndp13 The problem is just the use of the word "stack" rather than "stacks". Threads do share stacks since the stack is just a portion of virtual memory and threads share all virtual memory. Threads can even stash their stack pointers and the execution can be resumed by another thread with no issues. That one thread happens to be executing one stack at one particular time doesn't mean threads don't share stacks just like the fact that one thread is operating on a file descriptor at one time doesn't mean threads don't share file descriptors.

Comment: My wife and I each have our own car, but we also share those two cars. It is true that we each have our own car and it is also true that we share all our cars. We do have to coordinate whenever we need to use the other person's car for some reason. This is precisely what threads do with their stacks.

Answer (score 197):

First, let's look at the theoretical aspect.  You need to understand what a process is conceptually to understand the difference between a process and a thread and what's shared between them.

We have the following in section *2.2.2 The Classical Thread Model* of [Modern Operating Systems 3e](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639) by Tanenbaum:

> The process model is based on two independent concepts: resource
> grouping and execution. Sometimes it is use­ful to separate them;
> this is where threads come in....

He continues:

> One way of looking at a process is that it is a way to
> group related resources together. A process has an address space
> containing program text and data, as well as other resources. These
> resource may include open files, child processes, pending alarms,
> signal handlers, accounting information, and more. By putting them
> together in the form of a process, they can be managed more easily.
> The other concept a process has is a thread of execution, usually
> shortened to just thread. The thread has a program counter that keeps
> track of which instruc­tion to execute next. It has registers, which
> hold its current working variables. It has a stack, which contains the
> execution history, with one frame for each proce­dure called but not
> yet returned from. Although a thread must execute in some process, the
> thread and its process are different concepts and can be treated
> sepa­rately. Processes are used to group resources together; threads
> are the entities scheduled for execution on the CPU.

Further down he provides the following table:

```
Per process items             | Per thread items
------------------------------|-----------------
Address space                 | Program counter
Global variables              | Registers
Open files                    | Stack
Child processes               | State
Pending alarms                |
Signals and signal handlers   |
Accounting information        |
```

Let's deal with the [hardware multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29) issue.  Classically, a CPU would support a single thread of execution, maintaining the thread's state via a single [program counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) (PC), and set of registers.  But what happens when there's a cache miss?  It takes a long time to fetch data from main memory, and while that's happening the CPU is just sitting there idle.  So someone had the idea to basically have two sets of thread state (PC + registers) so that another thread (maybe in the same process, maybe in a different process) can get work done while the other thread is waiting on main memory.  There are multiple names and implementations of this concept, such as [Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) and [simultaneous multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29) (SMT for short).

Now let's look at the software side.  There are basically three ways that threads can be implemented on the software side.

1. User space threads
2. Kernel threads
3. A combination of the two

All you need to implement threads is the ability to save the CPU state and maintain multiple stacks, which can in many cases be done in user space.  The advantage of user space threads is super fast thread switching since you don't have to trap into the kernel and the ability to schedule your threads the way you like.  The biggest drawback is the inability to do blocking I/O (which would block the entire process and all its user threads),  which is one of the big reasons we use threads in the first place.  Blocking I/O using threads greatly simplifies program design in many cases.

Kernel threads have the advantage of being able to use blocking I/O, in addition to leaving all the scheduling issues to the OS.  But each thread switch requires trapping into the kernel which is potentially relatively slow.  However, if you're switching threads because of blocked I/O this isn't really an issue since the I/O operation probably trapped you into the kernel already anyway.

Another approach is to combine the two, with multiple kernel threads each having multiple user threads.

So getting back to your question of terminology, you can see that a process and a thread of execution are two different concepts and your choice of which term to use depends on what you're talking about.  Regarding the term "light weight process", I don't personally see the point in it since it doesn't really convey what's going on as well as the term "thread of execution".

Comment: Outstanding answer! It breaks down a lot of the jargon and assumptions. That does make this line stand out as awkward, though: "So someone had the idea to basically have two sets of thread state ( PC + registers )" -- what is the "PC" referred to here?

Comment: @Smithers The PC is the program counter, or instruction pointer, which gives the address of the next instruction to be executed:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter

Comment: I see what you did there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762418/process-vs-thread/19512075#19512075

Comment: 'The biggest drawback is the inability to do blocking I/O' By this does the author mean that it's possible but we don't do it normally or does it mean that an actual implementation of blocking io is not possible at all?

Comment: I always think that the ability to execute other processes while waiting for IO is called out-of-order execution.

Answer (score 165):

To explain more with respect to concurrent programming

> A process has a self-contained execution environment. A process generally has a complete, private set of basic run-time resources; in particular, each process has its own memory space.

> Threads exist within a process — every process has at least one. Threads share the process's resources, including memory and open files. This makes for efficient, but potentially problematic, communication.

Source: [The Java™ Tutorials: Processes and Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

An example keeping the average person in mind:

On your computer, open Microsoft Word and a web browser. We call these two *processes*.

In Microsoft Word, you type something and it gets automatically saved. Now, you have observed editing and saving happens in parallel - editing on one thread and saving on the other thread.

Comment: Maybe editing and saving are different processes.

Answer (score 60):

> An application consists of one or more processes. A process, in the simplest terms, is an executing program. One or more threads run in the context of the process. A thread is the basic unit to which the operating system allocates processor time. A thread can execute any part of the process code, including parts currently being executed by another thread. A fiber is a unit of execution that must be manually scheduled by the application. Fibers run in the context of the threads that schedule them.

Stolen from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684841(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: On other operating systems, such as Linux, there is no practical difference between the two at the operating system level, except that threads typically share the same memory space as the parent process.
(Hence my downvote)

Comment: Good answer (especially with crediting), as it shows the relation between the two and segues into an easily expected "next question" (about fibers).

Answer (score 46):

A process is a collection of code, memory, data and other resources. A thread is a sequence of code that is executed within the scope of the process. You can (usually) have multiple threads executing concurrently within the same process.

Answer (score 43):

**Process:**

1. Process is a heavy weight process.
2. Process is a separate program that has separate memory,data,resources ect.
3. Process are created using fork() method.
4. Context switch between the process is time consuming.

Example: 
Say, opening any browser (mozilla, Chrome, IE). At this point new process will start to execute.

**Threads:**

1. Threads are light weight processes.Threads are bundled inside the process.
2. Threads have a shared memory,data,resources,files etc.
3. Threads are created using clone() method.
4. Context switch between the threads are not much time consuming as Process.

Comment: In the Windows world you are correct, but in Linux every 'thread' is a process and are equally 'heavy' (or light).

Answer (score 34):

**Real world example for Process and Thread**
*This will give you the basic idea about thread and process*
[image]

*I borrowed the above info from Scott Langham's Answer* - thanks

Answer (score 27):

- Every process is a thread (primary thread).
- But every thread is not a process. It is a part(entity) of a process.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit further and/or include some evidence?

Answer (score 21):

http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9608/0191.html

> Linus Torvalds (torvalds@cs.helsinki.fi)
>
> Tue, 6 Aug 1996 12:47:31 +0300 (EET DST)
>
> Messages sorted by: [ date ][ thread ][ subject ][ author ]
>
> Next message: Bernd P. Ziller: "Re: Oops in get_hash_table"
>
> Previous message: Linus Torvalds: "Re: I/O request ordering"
>
> On Mon, 5 Aug 1996, Peter P. Eiserloh wrote:
>
> > We need to keep a clear the concept of threads. Too many people
> >     seem to confuse a thread with a process. The following discussion
> >     does not reflect the current state of linux, but rather is an
> >     attempt to stay at a high level discussion.
>
> NO!
>
> There is NO reason to think that "threads" and "processes" are
>   separate entities. That's how it's traditionally done, but I
>   personally think it's a major mistake to think that way. The only
>   reason to think that way is historical baggage.
>
> Both threads and processes are really just one thing: a "context of
>   execution". Trying to artificially distinguish different cases is just
>   self-limiting.
>
> A "context of execution", hereby called COE, is just the conglomerate
>   of  all the state of that COE. That state includes things like CPU
>   state  (registers etc), MMU state (page mappings), permission state
>   (uid, gid)  and various "communication states" (open files, signal
>   handlers etc). Traditionally, the difference between a "thread" and a
>   "process" has been mainly that a threads has CPU state (+ possibly
>   some other minimal state), while all the other context comes from the
>   process. However, that's just
>   *one* way of dividing up the total state of the COE, and there is nothing that says that it's the right way to do it. Limiting yourself
>   to that kind of image is just plain stupid.
>
> The way Linux thinks about this (and the way I want things to work) is
>   that there *is* no such thing as a "process" or a "thread". There is
>   only the totality of the COE (called "task" by Linux). Different COE's
>   can share parts of their context with each other, and one *subset* of
>   that sharing is the traditional "thread"/"process" setup, but that
>   should really be seen as ONLY a subset (it's an important subset, but
>   that importance comes not from design, but from standards: we obviusly
>   want to run standards-conforming threads programs on top of Linux
>   too).
>
> In short: do NOT design around the thread/process way of thinking. The
>   kernel should be designed around the COE way of thinking, and then the
>   pthreads *library* can export the limited pthreads interface to users
>   who  want to use that way of looking at COE's.
>
> Just as an example of what becomes possible when you think COE as
>   opposed  to thread/process:
>
> - You can do a external "cd" program, something that is traditionally impossible in UNIX and/or process/thread (silly example, but the idea 
>     is that you can have these kinds of "modules" that aren't limited to 
>     the traditional UNIX/threads setup). Do a:
>
> clone(CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS);
>
> child: execve("external-cd");
>
> /* the "execve()" will disassociate the VM, so the only reason we 
>   used CLONE_VM was to make the act of cloning faster */
>
> - You can do "vfork()" naturally (it meeds minimal kernel support, but  that support fits the CUA way of thinking perfectly):
>
> clone(CLONE_VM);
>
> child: continue to run, eventually execve()
>
> mother: wait for execve
>
> - you can do external "IO deamons":
>
> clone(CLONE_FILES);
>
> child: open file descriptors etc
>
> mother: use the fd's the child opened and vv.
>
> All of the above work because you aren't tied to the thread/process
>   way of thinking. Think of a web server for example, where the CGI
>   scripts are done as "threads of execution". You can't do that with
>   traditional threads, because traditional threads always have to share
>   the whole address space, so you'd have to link in everything you ever
>   wanted to do in the web server itself (a "thread" can't run another
>   executable).
>
> Thinking of this as a "context of execution" problem instead, your
>   tasks can now chose to execute external programs (= separate the
>   address space from the parent) etc if they want to, or they can for
>   example share everything with the parent *except* for the file
>   descriptors (so that the sub-"threads" can open lots of files without
>   the parent needing to worry about them: they close automatically when
>   the sub-"thread" exits, and it doesn't use up fd's in the parent).
>
> Think of a threaded "inetd", for example. You want low overhead
>   fork+exec, so with the Linux way you can instead of using a "fork()"
>   you write a multi-threaded inetd where each thread is created with
>   just CLONE_VM (share address space, but don't share file descriptors
>   etc). Then the child can execve if it was a external service (rlogind,
>   for example), or maybe it was one of the internal inetd services
>   (echo, timeofday) in which case it just does it's thing and exits.
>
> You can't do that with "thread"/"process".
>
> Linus

Comment: Love this email. To summarize it, the technical difference between a "thread" and "process" is the amount of shared state they have. Threads, for example, share a memory address space in a larger group. Processes all have isolated memory namespaces. They both, however, share a filesystem and network namespace (unlike a container). At the level of CoE, the exact distinction between "thread" and "process" isn't as important as "how private is each kernel resource" - Check out this tutorial for more on isolating linux resources - https://windsock.io/using-linux-namespaces-to-isolate-processes/

Comment: I was going to write a new response but after reading this email from Linus I better shut up.

Answer (score 20):

Both threads and processes are atomic units of OS resource allocation (i.e. there is a concurrency model describing how CPU time is divided between them, and the model of owning other OS resources). There is a difference in:

- Shared resources (threads are sharing memory by definition, they do not own anything except stack and local variables; processes could also share memory, but there is a separate mechanism for that, maintained by OS)
- Allocation space (kernel space for processes vs. user space for threads)

Greg Hewgill above was correct about the Erlang meaning of the word "process", and [here](http://www.erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2006-October/023287.html) there's a discussion of why Erlang could do processes lightweight.

Answer (score 19):

Trying to answer this question relating to Java world.

A process is an execution of a program but a thread is a single execution sequence within the process. A process can contain multiple threads. A thread is sometimes called a **lightweight process**.

For example:

Example 1:
A JVM runs in a single process and threads in a JVM share the heap belonging to that process. That is why several threads may access the same object. Threads share the heap and have their own stack space. This is how one thread’s invocation of a method and its local variables are kept thread safe from other threads. But the heap is not thread-safe and must be synchronized for thread safety.

Example 2:
A program might not be able to draw pictures by reading keystrokes. The program must give its full attention to the keyboard input and lacking the ability to handle more than one event at a time will lead to trouble. The ideal solution to this problem is the seamless execution of two or more sections of a program at the same time. Threads allows us to do this. Here Drawing picture is a process and reading keystroke is sub process (thread).

Comment: Good answer, I like that it defines its scope (Java world) and provides some applicable examples--including one (#2) that anyone who has to ask the original question can immediately relate to.

Comment: Also see the Oracle tutorial on this topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html, where it's clearly stated that "Most implementations of the Java virtual machine **run as a single process**. A Java application can create additional processes using a ProcessBuilder object. Multiprocess applications are beyond the scope of this lesson."

Answer (score 15):

Trying to answer it from Linux Kernel's OS View

A program becomes a process when launched into memory. A process has its own address space meaning having various segments in memory such as `.text` segement for storing compiled code, `.bss` for storing uninitialized static or global variables, etc. 
Each process would have its own program counter and user-space *stack*. 
Inside kernel, each process would have its own kernel stack (which is separated from user space stack for security issues) and a structure named `task_struct` which is generally abstracted as the process control block, storing all the information regarding the process such as its priority, state,(and a whole lot of other chunk). 
A process can have multiple threads of execution.

Coming to threads, they reside inside a process and share the address space of the parent process along with other resources which can be passed during thread creation such as filesystem resources, sharing pending signals, sharing data(variables and instructions) therefore making threads lightweight and hence allowing faster context switching. 
Inside kernel, each thread has its own kernel stack along with the `task_struct` structure which defines the thread. Therefore kernel views threads of same process as different entities and are schedulable in themselves. Threads in same process share a common id called as thread group id(`tgid`), also they have a unique id called as the process id (`pid`).

Answer (score 15):

For those who are more comfortable with learning by visualizing, here is a handy diagram I created to explain Process and Threads.
I used the information from MSDN - [About Processes and Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[image: Processes and Threads]

Comment: Might be interesting to add *another* process just to see how multithreading compares to multiprocessing.

Answer (score 14):

Both processes and threads are independent sequences of execution. The typical difference is that threads (of the same process) run in a shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces.

Process

Is a program in execution. it has text section i.e the program code, current activity as represented by the value of program counter & content of processors register. It also includes the process stack that contains temporary data(such as function parameters, return addressed and local variables), and a data section, which contains global variables. A process may also include a heap, which is memory that is dynamically allocated during process run time.

Thread

A thread is a basic unit of CPU utilisation; it comprises a thread ID, a program counter, register set, and a stack. it shared with other threads belonging to the same process its code section, data section and other operating system resources such as open files and signals.

-- Taken from Operating System by Galvin

Answer (score 12):

**Process:**

Process is basically a program in execution. It is an active entity.
Some operating systems use the term ‘task‘ to refer to a program that is being executed.
A process is always stored in the main memory also termed as the primary memory or random access memory.
Therefore, a process is termed as an active entity. It disappears if the machine is rebooted.
Several process may be associated with a same program.
On a multiprocessor system, multiple processes can be executed in parallel.
On a uni-processor system, though true parallelism is not achieved, a process scheduling algorithm is applied and the processor is scheduled to execute each process one at a time yielding an illusion of concurrency.
Example: Executing multiple instances of the ‘Calculator’ program. Each of the instances are termed as a process.

**Thread:**

A thread is a subset of the process.
It is termed as a ‘lightweight process’, since it is similar to a real process but executes within the context of a process and shares the same resources allotted to the process by the kernel.
Usually, a process has only one thread of control – one set of machine instructions executing at a time.
A process may also be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.
Multiple threads of control can exploit the true parallelism possible on multiprocessor systems.
On a uni-processor system, a thread scheduling algorithm is applied and the processor is scheduled to run each thread one at a time.
All the threads running within a process share the same address space, file descriptors, stack and other process related attributes.
Since the threads of a process share the same memory, synchronizing the access to the shared data withing the process gains unprecedented importance.

ref-https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/difference-between-process-and-thread

Comment: Sounds like Node concurrency in one process VS other language's multi-threads parallelism

Comment: This is literally copy-pasted from the answer below from 2010 ...

Answer (score 11):

1. A thread runs in a shared memory space, but a process runs in a separate memory space
2. A thread is a light-weight process, but a process is a heavy-weight process.
3. A thread is a subtype of process.

Comment: This feels very recursive. It would be a better answer perhaps if the relation between the thread and process were expanded upon.

Answer (score 11):

[Difference between Thread and Process?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/operating-systems/thread-vs-process/)

A process is an executing instance of an application and A thread is a path of execution within a process. Also, a process can contain multiple threads.It’s important to note that a thread can do anything a process can do. But since a process can consist of multiple threads, a thread could be considered a ‘lightweight’ process. Thus, the essential difference between a thread and a process is the work that each one is used to accomplish. Threads are used for small tasks, whereas processes are used for more ‘heavyweight’ tasks – basically the execution of applications.

Another difference between a thread and a process is that threads within the same process share the same address space, whereas different processes do not. This allows threads to read from and write to the same data structures and variables, and also facilitates communication between threads. Communication between processes – also known as IPC, or inter-process communication – is quite difficult and resource-intensive.

> Here’s a summary of the differences between threads and processes:

1. Threads are easier to create than processes since they 
   don't require a separate address space.
2. Multithreading requires careful programming since threads 
   share data strucures that should only be modified by one thread
   at a time.  Unlike threads, processes don't share the same 
   address space.
3. Threads are considered lightweight because they use far 
   less resources than processes.
4. Processes are independent of each other.  Threads, since they 
   share the same address space are interdependent, so caution 
   must be taken so that different threads don't step on each other.
   This is really another way of stating #2 above.
5. A process can consist of multiple threads.

Answer (score 10):

The following is what I got from one of the articles on [The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project). I guess it explains everything needed clearly.

> A thread is another mechanism for splitting the workload into separate
>   execution streams. A thread is lighter weight than a process. This
>   means, it offers less flexibility than a full blown process, but can
>   be initiated faster because there is less for the Operating System to
>   set up. When a program consists of two or more threads, all the
>   threads share a single memory space. Processes are given separate address spaces.
>   all the threads share a single heap. But each thread is given its own stack.

Comment: Not sure if this is clear, unless coming from a perspective that already understands threads vs processes. Adding in how they relate to each other might be useful.

Comment: Not clear. Does it mean only one process and its threads? What if there are many processes with many threads in each one? Do all those threads share a single memory space? Of all those processes?

Answer (score 10):

From the point of view of an interviewer, there are basically just 3 main things that I want to hear, besides obvious things like a process can have multiple threads:

1. Threads share same memory space, which means a thread can access memory from other's thread memory. Processes normally can not.
2. Resources. Resources (memory, handles, sockets, etc) are release at process termination, not thread termination.
3. Security. A process has a fixed security token. A thread, on the other hand, can impersonate different users/tokens.

If you want more, Scott Langham's response pretty much covers everything.
All these are from the perspective of an operating system. Different languages can implement different concepts, like tasks, light-wigh threads and so on, but they are just ways of using threads (of fibers on Windows).
There are no hardware and software threads. There are hardware and software **exceptions** and **interrupts**, or user-mode and kernel **threads**.

Comment: When you say security token, do you mean an user credential (username/pass) like one have on linux, for instance?

Comment: In windows this is a complex topic, the security token (actually called Access Token) is a big structure, containing all information required for access check. The structure is created after authorization, which means there's no username/password, but, a list of SIDs/right based on the username/password. More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8):

Coming from the embedded world, I would like to add that the concept of processes only exists in "big" processors (*desktop CPUs, ARM Cortex A-9*) that have MMU (memory management unit) , and operating systems that support using MMUs (such as *Linux*). With small/old processors and microcontrollers and small RTOS operating system (*real time operating system*), such as freeRTOS, there is no MMU support and thus no processes but only threads.

**Threads** can access each others memory, and they are scheduled by OS in an interleaved manner so they appear to run in parallel (or with multi-core they really run in parallel).

**Processes**, on the other hand, live in their private sandbox of virtual memory, provided and guarded by MMU. This is handy because it enables:

1. keeping buggy process from crashing the entire system.
2. Maintaining security by making other processes data invisible and
   unreachable. 
   The actual work inside the process is taken care by one or more threads.

Answer (score 8):

I've perused almost all answers there, alas, as an undergraduate student taking OS course currently I can't comprehend thoroughly the two concepts. I mean most of guys read from some OS books the differences i.e. threads are able to access to global variables in the transaction unit since they make use of their process' address space. Yet, the newly question arises why there are processes, cognizantly we know already threads are more lightweight vis-à-vis processes. Let's glance at the following example by making use of the image excerpted from [one of the prior answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41006780/4990642),

We have 3 threads working at once on a word document e.g. [Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org/). The first does spellchecking by underlining if the word is misspelt. The second takes and prints letters from keyboard. And the last does save document in every short times not to lose the document worked at if something goes wrong. *In this case, the 3 threads cannot be 3 processes since they share a common memory which is the address space of their process and thus all have access to the document being edited.* So, the road is the word document along with two bulldozers which are the threads though one of them is lack in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Process**: program under execution is known as process

**Thread**:  Thread is a functionality which is executed with the other part of the program based on the concept of "one with other"so thread is a part of process..

Comment: Not bad, though it introduces a new concept ("one with other") that is probably foreign to someone asking the question.

Comment: Post is formatted as code but should be normal text.

Answer (score 7):

1. Basically, a thread is a part of a process without process thread wouldn't able to work.
2. A thread is lightweight whereas the process is heavyweight.
3. communication between process requires some Time whereas thread requires less time.
4. Threads can share the same memory area whereas process lives in separate.

Answer (score 6):

While building an algorithm in Python (interpreted language) that incorporated multi-threading I was surprised to see that execution time was not any better when compared to the sequential algorithm I had previously built. In an effort to understand the reason for this result I did some reading, and believe what I learned offers an interesting context from which to better understand the differences between multi-threading and multi-processes.

Multi-core systems may exercise multiple threads of execution, and so Python should support multi-threading. But Python is not a compiled language and instead is an interpreted language<sup>1</sup>. This means that the program must be interpreted in order to run, and the interpreter is not aware of the program before it begins execution. What it does know, however, are the rules of Python and it then dynamically applies those rules. Optimizations in Python must then be principally optimizations of the interpreter itself, and not the code that is to be run. This is in contrast to compiled languages such as C++, and has consequences for multi-threading in Python. Specifically, Python uses the Global Interpreter Lock to manage multi-threading.

On the other hand a compiled language is, well, compiled. The program is processed "entirely", where first it is interpreted according to its syntactical definitions, then mapped to a language agnostic intermediate representation, and finally linked into an executable code. This process allows the code to be highly optimized because it is all available at the time of compilation. The various program interactions and relationships are defined at the time the executable is created and robust decisions about optimization can be made.

In modern environments Python's interpreter must permit multi-threading, and this must both be safe and efficient. This is where the difference between being an interpreted language versus a compiled language enters the picture. The interpreter must not to disturb internally shared data from different threads, while at the same time optimizing the use of processors for computations.

As has been noted in the previous posts both a process and a thread are independent sequential executions with the primary difference being that memory is shared across multiple threads of a process, while processes isolate their  memory spaces.

In Python data is protected from simultaneous access by different threads by the Global Interpreter Lock. It requires that in any Python program only one thread can be executed at any time. On the other hand it is possible to run multiple processes since the memory for each process is isolated from any other process, and processes can run on multiple cores.

---

<sup>1</sup> Donald Knuth has a good explanation of interpretive routines in The Art of Computer Programming: Fundamental Algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer I've found so far is [Michael Kerrisk's 'The Linux Programming Interface'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200):

> In modern UNIX implementations, each process can have multiple threads
> of execution. One way of envisaging threads is as a set of processes
> that share the same virtual memory, as well as a range of other
> attributes. Each thread is executing the same program code and shares
> the same data area and heap. However, each thread has it own stack
> containing local variables and function call linkage information. [LPI 2.12]

This book is a source of great clarity; Julia Evans mentioned its help in clearing up how Linux groups really work in [this article](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/11/20/groups/).

Comment: This seems directly self-contradictory. One part says a process can have more than one thread. The next part says a thread is a set of processes that share virtual memory. I don't see how both of these things can be true.

Comment: Here's how I read it: throw away the word 'have' in the first sentence. What you're left with, terminology-wise, is 1) a single thread and 2) a grouping of threads, which is known as a process for convenience sake. This is my take on what Kerrisk is after here.

Comment: What I think he's trying to say is that if you're used to the old UNIX view that processes are what the OS schedules then a set of threads is like a set of processes, except they share a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Right! Good way to put it.

Answer (score 4):

Threads within the same process share the Memory, but each thread has its own stack and registers, and threads store thread-specific data in the heap. Threads never execute independently, so the inter-thread communication is much faster when compared to inter-process communication.

Processes never share the same memory. When a child process creates it duplicates the memory location of the parent process. Process communication is done by using pipe, shared memory, and message parsing. Context switching between threads is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1: A JVM runs in a single process and threads in a JVM share the heap belonging to that process. That is why several threads may access the same object. Threads share the heap and have their own stack space. This is how one thread’s invocation of a method and its local variables are kept thread safe from other threads. But the heap is not thread-safe and must be synchronized for thread safety.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest way to understand the difference is to visualise how threads and processes execute their jobs.

---

***Threads*** are running **in parallel**, in a shared memory space (of the process that created them):

```
Thread 1              Thread 2              Thread 3
   | 
   | 
   |
                         |
                         |
                                               |
                                               |
                                               |
   |
                         |
                         | 
                         |            
Complete             Complete              Complete
```

*Note: The above can be interpreted as a process (i.e. one process with 3 threads)*

---

***Processes*** are running **in parallel and concurrently**:

```
Process 1              Process 2              Process 3
    |                      |                      |
    |                      |                      |
    |                      |                      |
    |                      |                      |
    |                      |                      |
    |                      |                      |
Complete               Complete               Complete
```

Comment: Your visualization shows that those threads are executing in concurrent manner and not in paralle

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Threads operate concurrent, but not necessarily in parallel. You can have threads on single-processor systems, where parallelism is impossible. In this situation, concurrency is achieved through time-sharing (interleaving of instructions) and improves throughput. This is the same for threads. Neither have to be parallel.

Answer (score 2):

They are almost as same... But the key difference is a thread is lightweight and a process is heavy-weight in terms of context switching, work load and so on.

Thread is a sub-process,they share common resources like code,data ,files within a process.Whereas the two processes cant share resources (Exceptions are if a process(parent) fork to make another process(child) then by default they can share resources.),demands high payload to resources to CPU whereas threads are much lighter in this Context .Although both posses same things.Scenario,consider a single threaded process is blocked due to an I/0,then the whole 1 will go to the waiting state but when multithreaded process is blocked by i/o,then its only 1 i/o concerned thread will be blocked .

Answer (score 2):

Consider process like a unit of ownership or what resources are needed by a task. A Process can have resources like memory space, specific input/output, specific files, and priority etc.

A thread is a dispatchable unit of execution or in simple words the progress through a sequence of instructions

Answer (score 2):

Difference between process and thread are given below :

- Process is an executing instance of a program whereas Thread is the smallest unit of process .
- Process can be divided into multiple threads whereas Thread can not be divided.
- Process may be considered as a task whereas Thread may be considered as a task lightweight process.
- Process allocate separate memory space whereas Thread allocate shared memory space.
- Process is maintained by operating system whereas Thread is maintained by programmer.

Comment: Stating that a Thread is maintained by the programmer is wrong. There are User-level threads and Kernel-level threads. They can also be mapped 1:1, m:1, n:m. Some OS's also have an additional concept called Light-weight-processes (such as Solaris had).

Answer (score 1):

Process - Program in execution

Thread  - a thread is execution of the smallest sequence of programmed instructions

Eg- you want to calculate matrix multiplication you will write a program of 3 for loops inside  main and execute it .
Now this is your process.

Now the same program you can solve by creating threads and assigning each thread to execute result of row.
Each thread will work independently and the result will stored in an array. 
As the threads share the same memory inside a process .

In Both the cases result will be same.

Answer (score 0):

From Erlang Programming (2009): Erlang concurrency is fast and scalable. Its processes are lightweight in that the Erlang virtual machine does not create an OS thread for every created process. They are created, scheduled, and handled in the VM, independent of underlying operating system.

Erlang implements a preemptive scheduler, which allows each process to run for a set period of time without blocking a system thread for too long, which gives each process some cpu time to be executed. The number of system threads depends on the number of cores if I'm not mistaking, and processes can be removed from one thread and moved to another if the load becomes uneven, this is all handled by the Erlang scheduler.