# Thread - Can two processes run at a time

Tags: multiprocessing

I have been reading this everyone. That only one THREAD can execute within a PROCESS as the PROCESS memory is shared by it's THREADS. Now, can two PROCESSES execute at a time? as the memory allocated to PROCESSES is differenet

Comment: Isn't the point of threads to be able to run them in parallel?  If only one can execute at a time, that is rather useless.

Comment: what is `...at a time`?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in [any](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200469/2615940) these [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1762418/2615940) SO [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/344682/2615940).