# Understanding Linux virtual memory: valgrind's massif output shows major differences with and without --pages-as-heap

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind, virtual-memory, massif

I've read the documentation about this parameter,  but the difference is really huge! When enabled, the memory usage of a simple program (see below) is about **7 GB** and when it's disabled, the reported usage is about **160 KB**.

`top` also shows about 7 GB, which kinda **confirms** the result with `pages-as-heap=yes`.

(I have a theory, but I don't believe it would explain such huge difference, so - asking for some help).

What especially bothers me, is that most of the reported memory usage is used by `std::string`, while `what?` is never printed (meaning - the actual capacity is pretty small).

**I do need to use `pages-as-heap=yes` while profiling my app, I just wonder how to avoid the "false positives"**

---

The code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::string s;
        s += "aaaaa";
        s += "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        s += "bbbbbbbbbb";
        s += "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
        if (s.capacity() > 1024) std::cout << "what?" << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < 192; ++i ) workers.push_back(std::thread(&run));

    workers.back().join();
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ --std=c++11 -fno-inline -g3 -pthread`

With `pages-as-heap=yes`:

```
100.00% (7,257,714,688B) (page allocation syscalls) mmap/mremap/brk, --alloc-fns, etc.
->99.75% (7,239,757,824B) 0x54E0679: mmap (mmap.c:34)
| ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x545C3CF: new_heap (arena.c:438)
| | ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x545CC1F: arena_get2.part.3 (arena.c:646)
| |   ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x5463248: malloc (malloc.c:2911)
| |     ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CB7E76: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |       ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CF8E37: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |         ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CF9C69: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |           ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CF9D22: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |             ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CF9FB1: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |               ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x401252: run() (test.cpp:11)
| |                 ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x403929: void std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (functional:1700)
| |                   ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x403864: std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() (functional:1688)
| |                     ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4037D2: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
| |                       ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x4CE2C7E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |                         ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x51C96B8: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
| |                           ->53.63% (3,892,314,112B) 0x54E63DB: clone (clone.S:109)
| |                             
| ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x545C35B: new_heap (arena.c:427)
| | ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x545CC1F: arena_get2.part.3 (arena.c:646)
| |   ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x5463248: malloc (malloc.c:2911)
| |     ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CB7E76: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |       ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CF8E37: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |         ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CF9C69: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |           ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CF9D22: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |             ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CF9FB1: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |               ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x401252: run() (test.cpp:11)
| |                 ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x403929: void std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (functional:1700)
| |                   ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x403864: std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() (functional:1688)
| |                     ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4037D2: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
| |                       ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x4CE2C7E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |                         ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x51C96B8: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
| |                           ->35.14% (2,550,136,832B) 0x54E63DB: clone (clone.S:109)
| |                             
| ->10.99% (797,306,880B) 0x51CA1D4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:513)
|   ->10.99% (797,306,880B) 0x4CE2DC1: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|     ->10.99% (797,306,880B) 0x4CE2ECB: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       ->10.99% (797,306,880B) 0x401BEA: std::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*&&)()) (thread:138)
|         ->10.99% (797,306,880B) 0x401353: main (test.cpp:24)
|           
->00.25% (17,956,864B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
```

while with `pages-as-heap=no`:

```
96.38% (159,289B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->43.99% (72,704B) 0x4EBAEFE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| ->43.99% (72,704B) 0x40106B8: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
|   ->43.99% (72,704B) 0x40107C9: _dl_init (dl-init.c:30)
|     ->43.99% (72,704B) 0x4000C68: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
|       
->33.46% (55,296B) 0x40138A3: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:322)
| ->33.46% (55,296B) 0x53D126D: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:588)
|   ->33.46% (55,296B) 0x4EE9DC1: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|     ->33.46% (55,296B) 0x4EE9ECB: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       ->33.46% (55,296B) 0x401BEA: std::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*&&)()) (thread:138)
|         ->33.46% (55,296B) 0x401353: main (test.cpp:24)
|           
->12.12% (20,025B) 0x4EFFE37: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| ->12.12% (20,025B) 0x4F00C69: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|   ->12.12% (20,025B) 0x4F00D22: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|     ->12.12% (20,025B) 0x4F00FB1: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x401285: run() (test.cpp:14)
|       | ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x403929: void std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (functional:1700)
|       |   ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x403864: std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() (functional:1688)
|       |     ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x4037D2: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
|       |       ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x4EE9C7E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       |         ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x53D06B8: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
|       |           ->12.07% (19,950B) 0x56ED3DB: clone (clone.S:109)
|       |             
|       ->00.05% (75B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|       
->05.58% (9,216B) 0x40315B: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402FC2: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:488)
|   ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402D4B: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >*, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > const&, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:616)
|     ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402BDE: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > const&, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1090)
|       ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402A76: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > const&, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
|         ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402771: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > std::allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > const&, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (shared_ptr.h:594)
|           ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x402325: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > std::make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (shared_ptr.h:610)
|             ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x401F9C: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > std::thread::_M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >(std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>&&) (thread:196)
|               ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x401BC4: std::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*&&)()) (thread:138)
|                 ->05.58% (9,216B) 0x401353: main (test.cpp:24)
|                   
->01.24% (2,048B) 0x402C9A: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
  ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x402AF5: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::allocate(std::allocator<std::thread>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:488)
    ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x402928: std::_Vector_base<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
      ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x40244E: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::thread>(std::thread&&) (vector.tcc:412)
        ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x40206D: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<std::thread>(std::thread&&) (vector.tcc:101)
          ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x401C82: std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::push_back(std::thread&&) (stl_vector.h:932)
            ->01.24% (2,048B) 0x401366: main (test.cpp:24)
```

---

<sub>Please ignore the crappy handling of the threads, it's just a very short example.</sub>

---

## UPDATE

It appears, that this is not related to `std::string` at all. As @Lawrence suggested, this can be reproduced by simply allocating a single `int` on the heap (with `new`). I believe @Lawrence is very close to the real answer here, quoting his comments (easier for further readers):

Lawrence:

> @KirilKirov The string allocation is not actually taking that much
>   space... Each thread gets it's initial stack and then heap access maps
>   some large amount of space (around 70m) that gets inaccurately
>   reflected. You can measure it by just declaring 1 string and then
>   having a spin loop... the same virtual memory usage is shown –
>   Lawrence Sep 28 at 14:51

me:

> @Lawrence - you're damn right! OK, so, you're saying (and it appears
>   to be like this), that on each thread, on the first heap allocation,
>   the memory manager (or the OS, or whatever) dedicates huge chunk of
>   memory for the threads' heap needs? And this chunk will be reused
>   later (or shrinked, if necessary)? – Kiril Kirov Sep 28 at 15:45

Lawrence:

> @KirilKirov something of that nature... exact allocations probably depends on malloc implementation and whatnot – Lawrence 2 days ago

Comment: I would suspect that the freed memory from the destroyed strings is not actually returned to the OS on a level below your program so that without `pages-as-heap` Massif thinks that the memory has been completely freed even though glibc (probably) keeps it around - the output of [`malloc_stats`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) might be interesting here.

Comment: You are measuring virtual memory being allocated. e.g each thread gets default stack size of `ulimit -s` (normally 8MB) and this will be reflected in 'memory used' even if never placed into physical memory. string creation and resize probably brings in lots of library code that gets it's own mmap'd space

Comment: @hlt that's exactly my theory, I also thought so, but still - this is a huge difference here. Can you give me a bit more pointers about `malloc_stats` - I read it, but not sure how this will help, as the output is a bit strange. Will dig deeper on this.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm aware of that, but 193 threads * 8 MB is about 1.5GiB and we're talking about 7 GiB here. I'm also aware of the loaded libraries, but they are definitely not that much. As `massif` reports, the key is in the string's allocations, I just wonder why they are so damn much.

Comment: @KirilKirov The string allocation is not actually taking that much space... Each thread gets it's initial stack and then heap access maps some large amount of space (around 70m) that gets inaccurately reflected. You can measure it by just declaring 1 string and then having a spin loop... the same virtual memory usage is shown

Comment: @Lawrence - that's a damn good point. Will try that and will run some additional tests. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @Lawrence - you're damn right! OK, so, you're saying (and it appears to be like this), that on each thread, on the *first* heap allocation, the memory manager (or the OS, or whatever) dedicates huge chunk of memory for the threads' heap needs? And this chunk will be reused later (or shrinked, if necessary)?

Comment: @KirilKirov something of that nature... exact allocations probably depends on malloc implementation and whatnot

Comment: What does Valgrind exp-dhat say? (This will profile memory use patterns).

Comment: No idea what this is, will check and try that tomorrow

Comment: I gave it a go and didn't see much in the way of excessive memory size.

Comment: @PaulFloyd yeah, I just confirmed that too..

Comment: @Lawrence - can you convert your comment into an answer? It will be easier for others to see it, I find it really useful and closest to the real situation (at least at the moment)

Comment: Could you clarify which column of `top` output you looked at? Did you look at VIRT, RSS or SHR, or a completely different column? Sorry for the late comment; but this info could be useful for people looking at similar problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`massif` with `--pages-as-heap=yes` and the `top` column you are observing both measure the virtual memory used by a process. This virtual memory includes all space `mmap`'d in the implementation of malloc and during the creation of threads. For example, the default stack size for a thread will be `8192k` which is reflected in the creation of each thread and contributes to the virtual memory footprint.

The specific allocation scheme will be dependent on implementation but it seems that the first heap allocation on a new thread will `mmap` roughly 65 megabytes of space. This can be viewed by looking at the [pmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) output for a process.

Excerpt from a very similar program to the example:

```
75170:   ./a.out
0000000000400000     24K r-x-- a.out
0000000000605000      4K r---- a.out
0000000000606000      4K rw--- a.out
0000000001b6a000    200K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f669dfa4000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f669dfa5000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f669e7a5000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f669e7a6000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f669efa6000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007f669efa7000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
...
00007f66cb800000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f66cc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f66cc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007f66d0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f66d0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007f66d4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f66d4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
...
00007f6880586000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6880d86000   1056K r-x-- libm-2.23.so
00007f6880e8e000   2044K ----- libm-2.23.so
...
00007f6881c08000      4K r---- libpthread-2.23.so
00007f6881c09000      4K rw--- libpthread-2.23.so
00007f6881c0a000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6881c0e000    152K r-x-- ld-2.23.so
00007f6881e09000     24K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6881e33000      4K r---- ld-2.23.so
00007f6881e34000      4K rw--- ld-2.23.so
00007f6881e35000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffe9d75b000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffe9d7f8000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffe9d7fb000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total          7815008K
```

It seems that malloc becomes more conservative as you approach some threshold of virtual memory per process. Also, my comment about libraries being mapped separately was misguided (they should be shared per process)

Comment: I'll award the bounty and accept this answer, as it helped me damn much and actually gave me the correct pointers - to understand the bigger picture, to know what to look for in google and to actually understand what happens. Later, I'll try to write a more detailed summary of what actually happens and will give some useful links in a separate answer.
Thanks, that really helped a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to write a short summary of what I learned, while trying to figure out what's happening.
**Note:** this answer is possible thanks to @Lawrence - appreciated!

---

## Long story short

This has absolutely nothing to do with Linux/kernel (virtual) memory management, nor with `std::string`.
It's all about the `glibc`'s memory allocator - **it just allocates huge areas of memory on the first (and not only, of course) dynamic allocation (per thread)**.

---

## Details

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < 192; ++i )
        workers.emplace_back([]{
            const auto x = std::make_unique<int>(rand());
            while (true) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));});
    workers.back().join();
}
```

Please ignore the crappy handling of the threads, I wanted this to be as short as possible.

#### Commands

Compile: `g++ --std=c++14 -fno-inline -g3 -O0 -pthread test.cpp`.
Profile: `valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=[no|yes] ./a.out`

#### Memory usage

`top` shows `7'815'012` KiB virtual memory.
`pmap` also shows `7'815'016` KiB virtual memory.
Similar result is shown by `massif` with `pages-as-heap=yes`: `7'817'088` KiB, see below.
On the other hand, `massif` with `pages-as-heap=no` is drastically different - around 133 KiB!

#### Massif output with pages-as-heap=yes

Memory usage before killing the program:

```
100.00% (8,004,698,112B) (page allocation syscalls) mmap/mremap/brk, --alloc-fns, etc.
->99.78% (7,986,741,248B) 0x54E0679: mmap (mmap.c:34)
| ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x545C3CF: new_heap (arena.c:438)
| | ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x545CC1F: arena_get2.part.3 (arena.c:646)
| |   ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x5463248: malloc (malloc.c:2911)
| |     ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x4CB7E76: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |       ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x4026D0: std::_MakeUniq<int>::__single_object std::make_unique<int, int>(int&&) (unique_ptr.h:765)
| |         ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x400EC5: main::{lambda()
| |           ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x40225C: void std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |             ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x402194: std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |               ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x402102: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |                 ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x4CE2C7E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |                   ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x51C96B8: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
| |                     ->46.11% (3,690,987,520B) 0x54E63DB: clone (clone.S:109)
| |                       
| ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x545C35B: new_heap (arena.c:427)
| | ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x545CC1F: arena_get2.part.3 (arena.c:646)
| |   ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x5463248: malloc (malloc.c:2911)
| |     ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x4CB7E76: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |       ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x4026D0: std::_MakeUniq<int>::__single_object std::make_unique<int, int>(int&&) (unique_ptr.h:765)
| |         ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x400EC5: main::{lambda()
| |           ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x40225C: void std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |             ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x402194: std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |               ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x402102: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| |                 ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x4CE2C7E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| |                   ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x51C96B8: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
| |                     ->33.53% (2,684,354,560B) 0x54E63DB: clone (clone.S:109)
| |                       
| ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x51CA1D4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:513)
|   ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x4CE2DC1: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|     ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x4CE2ECB: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x40139A: std::thread::thread<main::{lambda()
|         ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x4012AE: _ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt6threadE9constructIS1_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvPT_DpOT0_ (new_allocator.h:120)
|           ->20.13% (1,611,399,168B) 0x401075: _ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt6threadEE9constructIS0_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvRS1_PT_DpOT0_ (alloc_traits.h:527)
|             ->19.19% (1,535,864,832B) 0x401009: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<main::{lambda()
|             | ->19.19% (1,535,864,832B) 0x400F47: main (test.cpp:10)
|             |   
|             ->00.94% (75,534,336B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|             
->00.22% (17,956,864B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
```

#### Massif output with pages-as-heap=no

Memory usage before killing the program:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 68      2,793,125          143,280          136,676         6,604            0
95.39% (136,676B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->50.74% (72,704B) 0x4EBAEFE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
| ->50.74% (72,704B) 0x40106B8: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
|   ->50.74% (72,704B) 0x40107C9: _dl_init (dl-init.c:30)
|     ->50.74% (72,704B) 0x4000C68: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
|       
->36.58% (52,416B) 0x40138A3: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:322)
| ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x53D126D: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:588)
|   ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x4EE9DC1: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|     ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x4EE9ECB: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
|       ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x40139A: std::thread::thread<main::{lambda()
|         ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x4012AE: _ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt6threadE9constructIS1_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvPT_DpOT0_ (new_allocator.h:120)
|           ->36.58% (52,416B) 0x401075: _ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt6threadEE9constructIS0_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvRS1_PT_DpOT0_ (alloc_traits.h:527)
|             ->34.77% (49,824B) 0x401009: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<main::{lambda()
|             | ->34.77% (49,824B) 0x400F47: main (test.cpp:10)
|             |   
|             ->01.81% (2,592B) 0x4010FF: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<main::{lambda()
|               ->01.81% (2,592B) 0x40103D: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<main::{lambda()
|                 ->01.81% (2,592B) 0x400F47: main (test.cpp:10)
|                   
->06.13% (8,784B) 0x401B4B: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
| ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x401A60: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|   ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x40194D: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|     ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x401894: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|       ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x40183A: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|         ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x4017C7: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|           ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x4016AB: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|             ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x40155E: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()
|               ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x401374: std::thread::thread<main::{lambda()
|                 ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x4012AE: _ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt6threadE9constructIS1_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvPT_DpOT0_ (new_allocator.h:120)
|                   ->06.13% (8,784B) 0x401075: _ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaISt6threadEE9constructIS0_IZ4mainEUlvE_EEEvRS1_PT_DpOT0_ (alloc_traits.h:527)
|                     ->05.83% (8,352B) 0x401009: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<main::{lambda()
|                     | ->05.83% (8,352B) 0x400F47: main (test.cpp:10)
|                     |   
|                     ->00.30% (432B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|                     
->01.43% (2,048B) 0x403432: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->01.43% (2,048B) 0x4032CF: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::allocate(std::allocator<std::thread>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:488)
|   ->01.43% (2,048B) 0x4030B8: std::_Vector_base<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
|     ->01.43% (2,048B) 0x4010B6: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<main::{lambda()
|       ->01.43% (2,048B) 0x40103D: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<main::{lambda()
|         ->01.43% (2,048B) 0x400F47: main (test.cpp:10)
|           
->00.51% (724B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
```

### What the freak happens?

#### pages-as-heap=no

With `pages-as-heap=no` the things look reasonable - let's not inspect it. As expected, everything ends up with `malloc/new/new[]` and the memory usage is small enough not to worry us - these are the high level allocations.

#### pages-as-heap=yes

But see `pages-as-heap=yes`? ~8GiB virtual memory with this simple code?

Let's inspect the stack traces.

**`pthread_create`**

Let's start with the easier one: the one, that ends with `pthread_create`.

`massif` reports `1,611,399,168` bytes of allocated memory - this is exactly 192 * 8'196 KiB, meaning - 192 threads * 8MiB, [which is the default max stack size of a thread in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473416/2787).

**Note**, that 8'196 KiB is not exactly 8 MiB (8'192 KiB). I don't know where this difference comes from, but it's not significant at the moment.

**`std::make_unique<int>`**

OK, let's now see the other two stacks... wait, they are exactly the same? Yeah, `massif`'s documentation explains this, I didn't completely understand it, but it's also not significant. They show exactly the same stack. Let's combine the results and examine them together.

The memory usage from these two stacks combined is `6'375'342'080` bytes and all of them are caused by our simple `std::make_unique<int>`!

Let's take a step back: if we run the same experiment, but with a simple thread, we will see, that this `int` allocation causes allocating `67'108'864` bytes of memory, which is exactly 64 MB. What happens??

It all comes down to the implementation of `malloc` (as we all know, that `new/new[]` is internally implemented with `malloc`.. by default).

`malloc` internally uses a memory allocator, called `ptmalloc2` - the default memory allocator in Linux, that supports threads.

Simply put, this allocator deals with the following terms:

- `per thread arena`: a huge area of memory; usually per thread, for performance reasons; not all software threads have their own *per-thread-arenas*, this usually depends on the number of hardware threads (and other details, I guess);
- `heap`: the `arena`s are divided into heaps;
- `chunks`: the `heap`s are divided into smaller areas of memory, called `chunks`.

There are a lot of details about these things, will post some interesting links a bit later, although this should be enough for the reader to do their own research - these are really low-level and deep things, related to C++ memory management.

So, let's go back to our test with a single thread - allocated 64 MiB for a single `int`?? Let's see again the stack trace and concentrate at its end:

```
mmap (mmap.c:34)
new_heap (arena.c:438)
arena_get2.part.3 (arena.c:646)
malloc (malloc.c:2911)
```

Surprise, surprise: `malloc` calls `arena_get2`, which calls `new_heap`, which leads us to `mmap` (`mmap` and `brk` are the low level system calls, used for memory allocation in Linux). And this is reported to allocate exactly 64 MiB memory.

OK, let's now go back to our original example with the 192 threads and our huge number `6'375'342'080` - this is *exactly* 95 * 64 MiB!

Why exactly 95 - I can't really say, I stopped digging, but the fact, that the big number is divisible to 64 MiB was good enough for me.

You can dig a lot deeper, if necessary.

### Useful links

Really cool explanatory article: [Understanding glibc malloc](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-glibc-malloc/), by sploitfun

A more formal/official documentation: [The GNU allocator](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-GNU-Allocator.html#The-GNU-Allocator)

A cool stack exchange question: [How does glibc malloc works](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15033/how-does-glibc-malloc-work)

Others:

- https://zgqallen.github.io/2017/08/03/linux-glic-mm-overview/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation
- https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Ferguson/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-ferguson-WP.pdf
- [heap management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501189/heap-management)

If some of these links are broken at the moment of reading this post, it should be fairly easy to find similar articles. This topic is very popular, if you know what to look for and how.

### Thanks

I hope these observations give good high-level description of the whole picture and also give enough food for further extended research.

Feel free to comment / (suggest) edit / correct / extend / etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation:

> --pages-as-heap= [default: no]
>   Tells Massif to profile memory at the page level rather than at the malloc'd block level. See above for details.

So, according to the documentation, changing this setting changes what is measured; not what is allocated.

IF YES, you are measuring the number of pages.
If NO, you are measuring malloc blocks.

Comment: The point is - where do these pages come from. Also, without this option, I can't see the memory mapped files (which are a thing in the original source).

Comment: You are not getting memory mapped files. You are getting memory mapped to your address space when you call malloc. The mmap system service does a lot of different things depending upon the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a "kind of" answer (from the Valgrind perspective). The problem of memory pools, in particular with C++ strings, has been known for some time. The [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports) has a section on leaks in C++ strings, suggesting you try to set the GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW environment variable.

Additionally, for GCC6 and later, Valgrind has added hooks to cleanup still reachable memory in libstdc++. The Valgrind bugzilla entry is [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345307) and the GCC one is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69945).

I don't see why such small allocations blow up to so many gigabytes (over 12 Gbytes for a 64bit executable, CentOS 6.6, GCC 6.2).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, it's really interesting! But I still think @Lawrence is closer to the real answer here.

Comment: There does seem to be a large per-thread memory pool. Unfortunately Massif doesn't trace this.