# What is the difference between a thread/process/task?

Tags: process, task, terminology

What is the difference between a thread/process/task?

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Process:

A process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed.
It contains the program code and its current activity.
Depending on the operating system (OS), a process may be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.
Process-based multitasking enables you to run the Java compiler at the same time that you are using a text editor.
In employing multiple processes with a single CPU,context switching between various memory context is used.
Each process has a complete set of its own variables.

### Thread:

A thread is a basic unit of CPU utilization, consisting of a program counter, a stack, and a set of registers.
A thread of execution results from a fork of a computer program into two or more concurrently running tasks.
The implementation of threads and processes differs from one operating system to another, but in most cases, a thread is contained inside a process.        Multiple threads can exist within the same process and share resources such as memory, while different processes do not share these resources.
Example of threads in same process is automatic spell check and automatic saving of a file while writing.
Threads are basically processes that run in the same memory context.
Threads may share the same data while execution.
[Thread Diagram i.e. single thread vs multiple threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwH8u.jpg)

### Task:

A task is a set of program instructions that are loaded in memory.

Comment: Process and threads are related but otherwise orthogonal concepts. A thread is what the CPU actually runs; it's about scheduling access to shared resources (e.g. the CPU). A process is the allocated memory for instructions and data (a process needs memory for code and data). Of course a process will need one or more threads b/c that is what is actually run by the CPU. Multiple threads just means that the process gets more time slices on the same CPU or get to run on more CPUs concurrently. Think of a thread as a slice of time and a process as a slice of space (a region of memory in this case).

Answer (score 18):

Short answer:

A thread is a scheduling concept, it's what the CPU actually 'runs' (you don't run a process). A process needs at least one thread that the CPU/OS executes.

A process is data organizational concept. Resources (e.g. memory for holding state, allowed address space, etc) are allocated for a process.

Answer (score 13):

To explain on simpler terms

**Process**: process is the set of instruction as code which operates on related data and process has its own various state, sleeping, running, stopped etc. when program gets loaded into memory it becomes process. Each process has atleast one thread when CPU is allocated called sigled threaded program.

**Thread**: thread is a portion of the process. more than one thread can exist as part of process. Thread has its own program area and memory area. Multiple threads inside one process can not access each other data. Process has to handle sycnhronization of threads to achieve the desirable behaviour.

**Task**: Task is not widely concept used worldwide. when program instruction is loaded into memory people do call as process or task. Task and Process are synonyms nowadays.

Comment: I question the accuracy of the statement "Multiple threads inside one process can not access each other data." If the threads have their own data, it is by intent, policy or convention. They certainly CAN access each other's data even if they should not and they often work purposefully and cooperatively on the same data.

Comment: Multiple threads inside one process can not access each other data.  this line is correct ..? We know Threads are not independent of one other like processes as a result threads shares with other threads their code section, data section, OS resources.

Comment: Typo. Change to "Multiple threads inside one process can access each others' data"

Answer (score 9):

A `process` invokes or initiates a program. It is an instance of a program that can be multiple and running the same application. A `thread` is the smallest unit of execution that lies within the process. A process can have multiple threads running. An execution of thread results in a task. Hence, in a multithreading environment, multithreading takes place.

A `program` in execution is known as `process`. A program can have any number of processes. Every process has its own address space.

Threads uses address spaces of the process. The difference between a thread and a process is, when the CPU switches from one process to another the current information needs to be saved in Process Descriptor and load the information of a new process. Switching from one thread to another is simple.

A `task` is simply a set of instructions loaded into the memory. Threads can themselves split themselves into two or more simultaneously running tasks.

for more Understanding refer the link: http://www.careerride.com/os-thread-process-and-task.aspx

Comment: That link just points to a website scraping stackoverflow and repeating the answers already posted here.  If you're not a fan of recursion, don't click the link.

Answer (score 3):

from wiki clear explanation

1:1 (Kernel-level threading)

Threads created by the user are in 1-1 correspondence with schedulable entities in the kernel.[3] This is the simplest possible threading implementation. Win32 used this approach from the start. On Linux, the usual C library implements this approach (via the NPTL or older LinuxThreads). The same approach is used by Solaris, NetBSD and FreeBSD.

N:1 (User-level threading)

An N:1 model implies that all application-level threads map to a single kernel-level scheduled entity;[3] the kernel has no knowledge of the application threads. With this approach, context switching can be done very quickly and, in addition, it can be implemented even on simple kernels which do not support threading. One of the major drawbacks however is that it cannot benefit from the hardware acceleration on multi-threaded processors or multi-processor computers: there is never more than one thread being scheduled at the same time.[3] For example: If one of the threads needs to execute an I/O request, the whole process is blocked and the threading advantage cannot be utilized. The GNU Portable Threads uses User-level threading, as does State Threads.

M:N (Hybrid threading)

M:N maps some M number of application threads onto some N number of kernel entities,[3] or "virtual processors." This is a compromise between kernel-level ("1:1") and user-level ("N:1") threading. In general, "M:N" threading systems are more complex to implement than either kernel or user threads, because changes to both kernel and user-space code are required. In the M:N implementation, the threading library is responsible for scheduling user threads on the available schedulable entities; this makes context switching of threads very fast, as it avoids system calls. However, this increases complexity and the likelihood of priority inversion, as well as suboptimal scheduling without extensive (and expensive) coordination between the userland scheduler and the kernel scheduler.

Comment: remember thread library which we use to create thread are the responsible for thread scheduling inside process.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) sums it up quite nicely:

Threads compared with processes

Threads differ from traditional multitasking operating system processes in that:

- processes are typically independent, while threads exist as
  subsets of a process
- processes carry considerable state information, whereas multiple
  threads within a process share state
  as well as memory and other resources
- processes have separate address spaces, whereas threads share their
  address space
- processes interact only through system-provided inter-process
  communication mechanisms.
- Context switching between threads in the same process is
  typically faster than context
  switching between processes.

Systems like Windows NT and OS/2 are said to have "cheap" threads and "expensive" processes; in other operating systems there is not so great a difference except the cost of address space switch which implies a TLB flush.

Task and process are used synonymously.