# what is the algorithm to handle multiple clients in socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am  proceeding to make a code for handling multiple clients in socket programming but i am not having idea for even the algorithm. I dont know how to proceed. Can anyone help  me with the algorithm ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The "algorithm" is probably "multi-threading"...

Comment: either multi-threading (pthreads) or multiprocess (fork).

Comment: What kind of protocol? It's quite common to handle multiple UDP clients from a single-threaded server. Certainly doable with TCP too, just use `select()`.

Comment: There is a huge variety of techniques, summarized in the [C10K overview](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), which also has a good bibliography on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would download the Apache code - It achieves this and seems to be a reasonable algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The one which I think would be good is by having a multithreaded server with each thread listening on a single port or multiple ports.

Though there is a possibility of creating a multiprocess server I still recomend using a multi-threaded one. Reasons are in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)

Comment: First, it any case, there is a single thread which is actually _listening_ the port (the one that calls `accept()`). Second, to recommend a multi-threaded over multiprocess is similar to recommending a fork over a spoon not asking what is on the plate.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should try to use either event-driven model(like select()) or multi-thread model. It depends on what you intend to do.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple chat in Java once. You can check out the source here:
[github.com/Samuirai/Java](https://github.com/Samuirai/java/tree/master/chat)

The basic design is the following:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
System.out.println("Server started");
while (true) {
   Socket client = serverSocket.accept();   
   System.out.println("Client connected");
   ClientConnection conn = new ClientConnection(client, this);
   this.connections.add(conn);
   new Thread(conn).start();
}
```

The Server waits for a client to connect. When a Client connects, it adds a new *Connection* to a *List* and starts a *Thread* which handles the connection with the *Client*. The Project has three important files you should check out: [ChatServer](https://github.com/Samuirai/java/blob/master/chat/src/de/ilp/chat/server/ChatServer.java), [ChatClient](https://github.com/Samuirai/java/blob/master/chat/src/de/ilp/chat/client/ChatClient.java) and [ClientConnection](https://github.com/Samuirai/java/blob/master/chat/src/de/ilp/chat/server/ClientConnection.java).
I hope the code is easy to understand.