# Tkinter and multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I was using the following code to examine if Tkinter works along with multithreading. But the following code doesn't work (the Gui becomes unresponsive as soon as it runs). Can anyone please explain why it doesn't work?

```
from threading import Thread 
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(window, text='Hello')
label.pack()

def func():
    i = 1
    while True:
        label['text'] = str(i)
        i += 1

Thread(target=func).start()
Thread(target=window.mainloop).start()
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because Tkinter doesn't support multithreading. Everything that interacts with a Tkinter widget needs to run in the main thread. If you want to use multithreading, put the GUI in the main thread and your other code in a worker thread, and communicate between them with a thread safe queue.

Comment: @Chandan: no. Frankly, I've rarely ever needed multithreading with a GUI app, and when I do I usually prefer multiprocessing over mulththreading. Are you _certain_ you need multiple threads, or are you simply assuming you do? You can do a lot of work in all of the spare cycles when the GUI isn't doing anything but waiting for events.

Comment: Here is what I need to do: Suppose, clicking a button starts a process and then when I click another button, the process stops(I used 'pause' command in subprocess to do this) and then clicking another button kills that child process. So the previous event starts again.

Comment: @Chandan: you definitely don't need multiple threads for that since you're already spawning another process.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between multithreading and multirocessing or give some reference? I don't know much about them.

Comment: @Chandan: if you don't know what threads are, you absolutely shouldn't be writing code that uses them. They add a lot of complexity and can cause very subtle bugs unless you're careful. Here's a SO question specifically related to the differences between threads and processes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread

Comment: Ok. I think now I understand the difference. But how to run multiple processes in python without using multiple threads?

Comment: @Chandan: comments aren't for extended discussions. If you have specific questions, ask them as questions on this site.