# Multiprocessing in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

How to run multiple processes in python without multithreading? For example consider the following problem:-

We have to make a Gui,which has a start button which starts a function(say, prints all integers) and there is a stop button, such that clicking it stops the function.

How to do this in Tkinter?

Comment: when you say "another process" do you literally mean another process -- spawning a .exe or equivalent? Or, when you say "process" do you really mean "some other function"? I find it hard to believe you would have a whole separate process just to print integers.

Comment: I meant some other function.

Comment: @Chandan: terminology is critically important when asking technical questions. There is a _huge_ difference between a process and a function in this context. You should edit your question to reflect that you don't intend to spawn other processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you need to bind the `Button` widget with the function which starts the working thread. For example:

```
import time
import threading
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.button = tk.Button(root)
        self.button.pack()
        self._resetbutton()
    def _resetbutton(self):
        self.running = False
        self.button.config(text="Start", command=self.startthread)
    def startthread(self):
        self.running = True
        newthread = threading.Thread(target=self.printints)
        newthread.start()
        self.button.config(text="Stop", command=self._resetbutton)
    def printints(self):
        x = 0
        while self.running:
            print(x)
            x += 1
            time.sleep(1) # Simulate harder task
```

With the `self.running` approach, you can end the thread gracefully only by changing its value. Note that the use of multiple threads serves to avoid blocking the GUI while `printints` is being executed.

I have read [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057341/tkinter-and-multi-threading) and I suppose why you explicitly asked here for a solution without multithreading. In Tkinter this solution can be used in a scenario where the other threads have to communicate with the GUI part. For example: filling a progressbar while some images are being rendered.

However, as it has been pointed in the comments, this approach is too complex for just printing numbers.

[Here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) you can find a lot of information and more examples about Tkinter.

---

**Edit:**

Since your new question has been closed, I'll change the code here to clarify the last point.

Comment: @BryanOakley I totally agree, but I suppose the use of the worker thread is for something more relevant than printing integers - i.e, process a big amount of data, which may block the GUI until it finishes.

Comment: the question specifically asks how to do this _without_ multithreading.

Comment: @A.Rodas How to do it without using two buttons? I mean can we change the text of the button from 'Start' to 'Stop' when the it starts and 'Stop' to 'Start' when it stops?

Comment: @BryanOakley you said that Tkinter doesn't support multithreading, then how does it work?(sorry, if I misunderstood the thing)

Comment: @Chandan: as long as nothing in a worker thread attempts to access any Tkinter data structures it will probably work. The problems come from trying to access GUI objects from more than one thread.

Comment: @Chandan Yes, it can be done by calling `config` with the new values. However, if you need a more detailed answer, it's better to ask it in a new question.

Comment: @Chandan I've edited the answer to include the change of the button.

Comment: @A.Rodas thank you million times for such brilliant answer which solved the very annoying screen freezing caused by **while loop**, I am sharing your code as **tkinter while loop** boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to used multiprocessing module? Seems to be the one you're looking for.