# Tkinter dilema about threading and async

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a dilema about an approach: I want to execute an OS command, more specifically I want to connect to WiFi. But the problem is: when I call the function it needs time to execute and the GUI freezes. I know why it hangs, I understand how tkinter works. What is my best option here? Should I use `Threading` or should I use `Asyncio`? I managed with threads but I did not manage to use async functions without the GUI freezing while executing the function. Can someone suggest some example code if I can do this with async or the safest way possbile?
Thank you.

Comment: Use one of the functions in the `subprocess` module that *doesn't* wait for the command to finish before returning.

Comment: Recently I was struggling to solve **while loop** screen freezing in tkinter and this brilliant answer solved it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057789/multiprocessing-in-python-tkinter#15058544

Comment: thank you , will try this tommorow :D