# Python Threadsafe Integer Decrease using locks

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locks

I have several workers process which should decrease a shared integer when the are finished.

To ensure Threadsafety i tried a lock but somehow it is not working, printing out workers at the end of the program will still output 4

I read http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/

```
workers = 4
lock = threading.Lock()

def workerStopped(id,lock):
    lock.acquire()
    global workers
    print "Decrease workers (" + str(workers) + ")for #" + str(id)
    workers = workers - 1
    print "Now " + str(workers) + " Workers"
    lock.release()

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue,ident,lock):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.queue= queue
        self.idstr= str(ident)
        self.lock = lock
        print "Ident" + self.idstr
  ......

workerStopped(self.idstr,self.lock)

 ....

for i in range(4):
    Worker( request_queue,i,lock ).start()
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed description than "somehow it is not working". Note that your code sample is not standalone, so we cannot run it and see for ourselves what the problem is.

Comment: See [difference between thread and process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread), as well as [shared counter with python multiprocessing](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing/)

Comment: workers is at the end still 4 ;) also it is always printed as 3 after calling worker stopped

Answer (score 0):

Thx to mtadd, he provided the link to http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing/

It seem that you have to share variables between different Process in another way than sharing between Threads

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Lock

def func(val, lock):
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        with lock:
            val.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Value('i', 0)
    lock = Lock()
    procs = [Process(target=func, args=(v, lock)) for i in range(10)]

    for p in procs: p.start()
    for p in procs: p.join()

    print v.value
```