# MultiProgramming , multi-threading, and parallel processing?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I was wondering if there are any slight difference between the definitions of :

- multiprogramming
- Multithreading
- Parallel processing

As I understand that we are using multithreading to achieve multiprogramming . Should the parallel processing the same as multiprogramming ,or it's related to hardware ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Multiprogramming** describes that you are able to run multiple programms on a computer at the same time (compared to an old eg DOS system where only one program at a time could run) (also sometimes refered as mutlitasking) -> [multiprogramming](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/multiprogramming)

**Multithreading** has to be seen differently on description: -> [multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading)

Hardware Multithreading or Architecture: a Processor is able to run multiple Threads in parallel (for real, counterexample: Multiprogramming)

Software Mutlithreading: is when one Process consists of multiple threads those threads are not independent to each other, like processes, especially those threads can have race conditions while working on the same data (-> [difference between thread & process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread) )

**Parallel processing** desribes that there are some ( > 1)  CPU's working togehter in any kind. This includes one PC with a multi-core, one server with multiple processors (eg on cards) or even a network of computers -> [Parallel processing](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Parallel_processing.html)

Answer (score 2):

The way I've usually seen your 2nd and 3rd terms used:

**Parallel processing** refers to two or more threads running at the same time, each working with their own data.  That is, beyond starting and stopping, there are few, if anym synchronization problems.  **Multithreading** refers to much the same thing, except that the threads share data and must be very careful about this.  That is, synchronization is everything.

Proper *parallel processing* is not much harder than running a single thread.  (Most platforms provide all kinds of support to help keep it simple.)  **Multithreading** is a lot of very hard work.