# Why was the comment that said "Don't format a floppy at the same time" funny when talking about threads and processes?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, format

I was reading up the difference between [Thread and Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread) and came across the comment left by users in the second answer which stated

> As so long as you don't format a floppy at the same time.

It has 27 upvotes but no one has explained the reason behind it .

I would like to know what the commentor means when he said the above comment ??

Can someone suggest a more meaningful question name which reflects what the question is asking

Comment: It is just a snarky remark about the way Windows 9x used to work.  It still had heavy MS-Dos compatibility built-in that could impact multi-tasking.  That's all long gone, as are the odds you'll ever run into a floppy disk drive that isn't in a museum.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/02/9265754.aspx

Answer (score 46):

In the early days of Windows, a floppy could be crashed when the formatting process was interrupted because of the floppy disk itself was still moving. So, if the 'multitasking operating system' Windows really executes a different time consuming task, you had to throw away your floppy. So the funny thing is, that Microsoft called that mess a 'multitasking operation system'.

Comment: I think you're referring to the early days of CD recorders, not floppies. It was indeed possible to cause a buffer underrun when writing a CD, purely because "Windows multitasking" would preempt the CDR authoring software when e.g. you moved windows around!

Comment: Yes you can't crash a floppy. The head rests on the platter. So while Microsoft can't write operating systems, it would be wrong to blame them for this, when it could not have happened. The worse that you would get, is having to format it again. However I have seen Microsoft's Windows refuse to format (create a file-system, but MS calls it formatting) a hard-disk, with error such as Operation failed: file system corrupt. I had to use a Unix machine to blank the disk, then MS-Windows could re-initialise the file-system.