# How to use the same buttons for different threads while multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I will try my best to describe what I need to know. I'm using C# (WPF .NET 4), multithreading by using a BlockingCollection. The threads contain infinite loops, so they are never going to die and they are going in turns (`1st - 2nd - 1st - 2nd` etc). While each thread is active it is showing in my GUI "Thread X is active".

Now, I have a couple of buttons on my GUI, but right now when I click `randomButton` it calls the same method from `thread 1` and `thread 2`.

How can I make it so it calls only the method from the active thread? Is there a way to write something in my thread that basically says "If this thread is active the buttons will only affect this thread"?

Comment: What is the effect you're trying to achieve? Show us your code

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, `button X` calls `method Y` on all threads. I want it to call `method Y` only on one thread. How?

Comment: It dosen't call `methodY` on all threads, it calls `methodY` inside your thread but affects your whole process

Comment: You can say to your threads to read from one BlockingCollection. When button pressed, just add some data to collection. So one thread get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of threading.

Lets define a Thread:

**Thread**

> A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources. In addition, each thread maintains exception handlers, a scheduling priority, thread local storage, a unique thread identifier, and a set of structures the system will use to save the thread context until it is scheduled. The thread context includes the thread's set of machine registers, the kernel stack, a thread environment block, and a user stack in the address space of the thread's process. Threads can also have their own security context, which can be used for impersonating clients.

When you run a method inside a `Thread` in your application, may it be a `Background Thread` or a `Foreground Thread`, you are executing a unit of work in parallel to the applications `Main Thread`, which in your case is the `UI Thread` of your GUI.

> "`How can I make it so it calls only the method from the active thread?`"

When you start a `Thread`, it runs until it has finished execution (either by finishing work or terminating due to an exception or thread abortion). So when you start multiple threads simultaneously, invoking same method, **they will all run it at the same time, since they are all active**

You can use [`Concurrent Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) which let you access collections inside a multithreaded environment

I suggest you read more about processes and threads [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)