# Python pool map and choosing number of processes

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, reduce

In setting the number of processes, I'd be keen to see how many threads I can actually use on my machine - how do I find this? Is there a way to determine the number of threads available to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to know the [CPU count?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#miscellaneous)

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool), when you start a pool and don't specify the number of processes, the default number is the number of cpu's on the system:

> processes is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is `None` then the number returned by `cpu_count()` is used. If initializer is not None then each worker process will call initializer(*initargs) when it starts.

Comment: Multiprocessing does not create threads, it starts processes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread Regardless, you can have more processes/threads than the number of CPUs, but you usually don't want to for performance reasons.

Comment: The exception to the "one thread/process per CPU" rule would be if you're doing I/O-bound work in most of your threads/processes. In that case, it makes sense to start more threads than you have CPUs, because while your thread are blocking on I/O they won't be using any CPU cycles.

Comment: @dano, I agree, but usually with pool.map you're performing homogeneous tasks.