# Running process count inside Android Service

Tags: android

How to get count of running process inside android service from **RunningServiceInfo**? 
    Is there anyway to get so?
Looks like I have create a confusion, Suppose I have a background service which have two thread inside and it is running. Now I can get service information from **RunningServiceInfo**, How counld I get the count of thread inside this service from **RunningServiceInfo**?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/GetRunningServicesInfo.htm tried ?

Comment: `RunningServiceInfo.clientCount`? Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @pskink No. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: you can get number of clients, not number of threads

Comment: @pskink Yeah, but I need count of thread inside this service

Comment: There's no such data in `RunningServiceInfo`, what do you need it for?

Comment: @pskink Any other way to do so?? please suggest, there must be some  way to do so. We can see this feature inside taskmanager app>Running Service> list of service(1 process 1 service)

Comment: so you have #processes and #services, not **#threads**

Comment: @pskink yes, this thread is shown as #process

Comment: no: process != thread, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Threads_vs._processes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread or http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/operating-systems/thread-vs-process/

Comment: @pskink yeah, I know. I just want to set analogy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67373/discussion-between-startcoding-and-pskink).