# What resources do threads share and not share?

Tags: multithreading

For some reason I cannot find the answers to this. Multiple threads can be associated with the same process. It's called a multithreaded process. One of the good things about multithreaded processes is that they share resources. But what resources do they share, and what resources do they not share?

I know there are both shared resources among threads of the same process, and there are resources that may not be shared among threads of the same process.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what CPU architecture and threading library/language you're asking about. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a process and a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread). Several answers can clarify things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They share a common view of **memory**. A pointer created in one thread is useable in another. Similarly, a value set in one thread will, with caveats, be visible in another thread.
2. They do not share a stack. Their stacks are located at different addresses in memory.