# Infinite loop in Erlang process

Tags: concurrency, erlang, infinite-loop

I'm very new to `Erlang` and tried to implement a simple `class` that has some methods to simulate a database. `insert()` just inserts a `key -> value` in the process map, and `retrieve()` just returns the value from the map. However, I am getting stuck in the `loop()`. What am I doing wrong?

```
-module(db).
-export([start/0,stop/0,retrieve/1,insert/2]).

start() ->
    register(db, spawn(fun() ->
              loop() 
          end)
        ),
    {started}.


insert(Key, Value) ->
    rpc({insert, Key, Value}).

retrieve(Key) ->
    rpc({retrieve, Key}).

stop() ->
    rpc({stop}).

rpc(Request) ->
    db ! {self(), Request},
    receive
    {db, Reply} ->
        Reply
    end.

loop() ->
    receive
    {rpc, {insert, Key, Value}} ->
        put(Key, Value),
        rpc ! {db, done},
        loop();
    {rpc, {retrieve, Key}} ->
        Val = get(Key),
        rpc ! {db, Val},
        loop();
    {rpc, {stop}} ->
        exit(db,ok),
        rpc ! {db, stopped}    
    end.
```

So, after compiling:

I first call `db:start().`
and then when trying `db:insert("A", 1).`, it gets stucked.

Thank you

Comment: First problem, before you go any further: Erlang *does not have classes or methods*. Everything is a function. Every function returns a value. There are [*processes*, not *classes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294367/erlang-process-vs-java-thread/32296577#32296577), though, and you can send them *messages*, but how they respond to them is defined in a very different way than methods.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I still don't understand how everything works in Erlang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `loop/0` function. You're using `rpc` atom to pattern match the messages received (`{rpc, {insert, Key, Value}}`), but, as you can see on `rpc/1` function, you always send messages with the format `{self(), Request}` to db process.

`self()` function returns a PID in the format `<X.Y.Z>`, which will never match against the atom `rpc`

For example, let's say you're trying to insert some data using the function `insert/2` and `self()` would return the PID `<0.36.0>`. When `rpc/1` sends the message, on the line `db ! {self(), {insert, Key, Value}}`, `loop/0` will receive `{<0.36.0>, {insert, Key, Value}}` message, which will never match against `{rpc, {insert, Key, Value}}`, because `rpc` is an atom.

The solution is to change `rpc` atom to a variable, like this:

```
loop() ->
receive
{Rpc, {insert, Key, Value}} ->
    put(Key, Value),
    Rpc ! {db, done},
    loop();
{Rpc, {retrieve, Key}} ->
    Val = get(Key),
    Rpc ! {db, Val},
    loop();
{Rpc, {stop}} ->
    Rpc ! {db, stopped},
    exit(whereis(db),ok)

end.
```

Erlang variables start with capital letters, that's why I used `Rpc`, instead of `rpc`.

P.S.: Actually, you had two other problems:

1. In the last part of `loop/0`, where you handle `stop` message, you call `exit(db, ok)` before you actually answer to `rpc`. In that case, you'd never receive the `{db, stopped}` message back from `db` process, which would be dead by that time. That's why I've changed the order, putting the `exit/2` call after `Rpc ! {db, stopped}`.
2. When you call `exit/2`, you were passing `db`, which is an atom, as the first argument, but `exit/2` function expects an PID as first argument, which would raise a `badarg` error. That's why I've changed it to `exit(whereis(db), ok)`.

Comment: You're welcome, @LuisLavieri. You should read zxq9's answer though, which refers to some important concerns about coding concurrent erlang.
You should also check OTP, for the sake of simplicity. Since you're new to Erlang, I'd recommend you [Learn You Some Erlang Book](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/). IMHO, it's the best way to start.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this a bit more carefully. What do you mean by "rpc"? "Remote Procedure Call" -- sure. But *everything* in Erlang is an rpc, so we tend not to use that term. Instead we distinguish between synchronous messages (where the caller blocks, waiting on a response) and aynchronous messages (where the caller just fires off a message and runs off without a care in the world). We tend to use the term "call" for a synch message and "cast" for an asynch message.

We can write that easily, as a call looks a lot like your rpc above, with the added idiom in Erlang of adding a unique reference value to tag the message and monitoring the process we sent a message to just in case it crashes (so we don't get left hanging, waiting for a response that will never come... which we'll touch on in your code in a bit):

```
% Synchronous handler
call(Proc, Request) ->
    Ref = monitor(process, Proc),
    Proc ! {self(), Ref, Request},
    receive
        {Ref, Res} ->
            demonitor(Ref, [flush]),
            Res;
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Proc, Reason} ->
            {fail, Reason}
    after 1000 ->
        demonitor(Ref, [flush]),
        {fail, timeout}
    end.
```

Cast is a bit easier:

```
cast(Proc, Message) ->
    Proc ! Message,
    ok.
```

The definition of call above means that the process we are sending to will receive a message of the form `{SenderPID, Reference, Message}`. Note that this is *different* than `{sender, reference, message}`, as lower-case values are [atoms](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67324), meaning they are their own values.

When we `receive` messages we are *matching* on the shape and values of the message received. That means if I have

```
receive
    {number, X} ->
        do_stuff(X)
end
```

in my code and the process sitting in that `receive` get a message `{blah, 25}` it *will not match*. If it receives *another* message `{number, 26}` then it will match, that `receive` will call `do_stuff/1` and the process will continue on. (These two things -- the difference between `atoms` and `Variables` and the way matching in `receive` works -- is why your code is hanging.) The initial message, `{blah, 25}` will still be in the mailbox, though, at the front of the queue, so the next `receive` has a chance to match on it. This property of mailboxes is immensely useful sometimes.

But what does a catch-all look like?

Above you are expecting three kinds of messages:

- `{insert, Key, Value}`
- `{retrieve, Key}`
- `stop`

You dressed them up differently, but that's the business end of what you are trying to do. Running the insert message through the `call/2` function I wrote above it would wind up looking like this: `{From, Ref, {insert, Key, Value}}`. So if we expect any response from the process's receive loop we will need to match on that exact form. How do we catch unexpected messages or badly formed ones? At the end of the `receive` clause we can put a single naked variable to match on *anything* else:

```
loop(State) ->
    receive
        {From, Ref, {insert, Key, Value}} ->
            NewState = insert(Key, Value, State),
            From ! {Ref, ok},
            loop(NewState);
        {From, Ref, {retrieve, Key}} ->
            Value = retrieve(Key, State),
            From ! {Ref, {ok, Value}},
            loop(State);
        {From, Ref, stop} ->
            ok = io:format("~tp: ~tp told me to stop!~n", [self(), From]),
            From ! {Ref, shutting_down},
            exit(normal)
        Unexpected ->
            ok = io:format("~tp: Received unexpected message: ~tp~n",
                           [self(), Unexpected]),
            loop(State)
    end.
```

You will notice that I am *not* using the process dictionary. DO NOT USE THE PROCESS DICTIONARY. This isn't what it is for. You'll overwrite something important. Or drop something important. Or... bleh, just don't do it. Use a dict or map or gb_tree or whatever instead, and pass it through as the process' `State` variable. This will become a very natural thing for you once you start writing OTP code later on.

Toy around with these things a bit and you will soon be happily spamming your processes to death.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am definitely trying this.