# Why does my loop require more memory on each iteration?

Tags: python, memory, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to reduce the memory requirements of my python 3 code. Right now each iteration of the for loop requires more memory than the last one.

I wrote a small piece of code that has the same behaviour as my project:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat


def simulation(steps, y):  # the function that starts the parallel execution of f()
    pool = Pool(processes=8, maxtasksperchild=int(steps/8))
    results = pool.starmap(f, zip(range(steps), repeat(y)), chunksize=int(steps/8))
    pool.close()
    return results


def f(steps, y):  # steps is used as a counter. My code doesn't need it.
        a, b = np.random.random(2)
        return y*a, y*b

def main():
    steps = 2**20  # amount of times a random sample is taken
    y = np.ones(5)  # dummy variable to show that the next iteration of the code depends on the previous one
    total_results = np.zeros((0,2))
    for i in range(5):
        results = simulation(steps, y[i-1])
        y[i] = results[0][0]
        total_results = np.vstack((total_results, results))

    print(total_results, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For each iteration of the for loop the threads in simulation() each have a memory usage equal to the total memory used by my code.

Does Python clone my entire environment each time the parallel processes are run, including the variables not required by f()? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Ideally I would want my code to only copy the memory it requires to execute f() while I can save the results in memory.

Comment: yes it clones the entire context of the program

Comment: You should guard those main operations with `if __name__ == '__main__':` at least.

Comment: @snakecharmerb results[0][0] is just a float.

Comment: @Ilja Yes, good point. I do this in my real code but I figured for this example it wasn't required. I'll insert it (but it doesn't change the behaviour).

Comment: What do you btw exactly mean by "the threads (processes) each have a memory usage equal to the total memory used by my code"? You're not mixing forking's [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) behaviour with actual mem usage perhaps? Which somewhat means "only copy the memory it requires to execute f()".

Comment: How are you measuring the memory consumption?

Comment: Been running the test script with larger and larger for loop iteration counts, but my memory consumption is pretty steady. Fluctuates quite a bit, but doesn't rise.

Comment: @Ilja I mean that, for example, if my code has 3% memory usage when it calls simulation(), each thread (as shown on htop) will start with 3% real memory (not virtual). Then on the next iteration my code will use more than 3% memory per thread because it also seems to copy the results and results_total array when creating new threads. The code doesn't seem to implement COW behaviour (if I understand it correctly) because each thread seems to take up actual physical memory the moment it starts execution.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I check htop's RES column.

Comment: @Isea after your edit I can observe the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Still at it, one thing came to mind: example code is example code, but in this case the whole multiprocess mapping simulation step could be replaced with `np.random.random((steps, 2)) * y[i - 1]`. Have you considered vectorization of the actual problem more thoroughly?

Comment: @Ilja Great to hear you're working on it! My real code involves constructing a matrix with the random values I generate and then calling np.linalg.eigh() on this matrix. Since the matrix needs to be generated for each set of random values I cannot use the solution you proposed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106650/discussion-between-ilja-and-isea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the script does use quite a bit of memory even with the "smaller" example values, the answer to

> Does Python clone my entire environment each time the parallel
>   processes are run, including the variables not required by f()? How
>   can I prevent this behaviour?

is that it does in a way *clone* the environment with [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) a new process, but if [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) semantics are available, no actual physical memory needs to be copied until it is written to. For example on this system

```
 % uname -a 
Linux mypc 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`COW` seems to be available and in use, but this may not be the case on other systems. On Windows this is strictly different as a new Python interpreter is executed from `.exe` instead of forking. Since you mention using `htop`, you're using some flavour of UNIX or UNIX like system, and you get `COW` semantics.

> For each iteration of the for loop the *processes* in simulation() each
>   have a memory usage equal to the total memory used by my code.

The spawned processes will display almost identical values of [`RSS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), but this can be misleading, because mostly they occupy the same actual physical memory mapped to multiple processes, if writes do not occur. With [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) the story is a bit more complicated, since it "chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks". This submitting happens over [`IPC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and submitted data will be copied. In your example the `IPC` and 2**20 function calls also dominate the CPU usage. Replacing the mapping with a single vectorized multiplication in `simulation` took the script's runtime from around 150s to *0.66s* on this machine.

We can observe `COW` with a (somewhat) simplified example that allocates a large array and passes it to a spawned process for read-only processing:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Condition, Event
from time import sleep
import psutil


def read_arr(arr, done, stop):
    with done:
        S = np.sum(arr)
        print(S)
        done.notify()
    while not stop.is_set(): 
        sleep(1)


def main():
    # Create a large array
    print('Available before A (MiB):', psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 ** 2)
    input("Press Enter...")
    A = np.random.random(2**28)
    print('Available before Process (MiB):', psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 ** 2)
    input("Press Enter...")
    done = Condition()
    stop = Event()
    p = Process(target=read_arr, args=(A, done, stop))
    with done:
        p.start()
        done.wait()
    print('Available with Process (MiB):', psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 ** 2)
    input("Press Enter...")
    stop.set()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output on this machine:

```
 % python3 test.py
Available before A (MiB): 7779.25
Press Enter...
Available before Process (MiB): 5726.125
Press Enter...
134221579.355
Available with Process (MiB): 5720.79296875
Press Enter...
```

Now if we replace the function `read_arr` with a function that modifies the array:

```
def mutate_arr(arr, done, stop):
    with done:
        arr[::4096] = 1
        S = np.sum(arr)
        print(S)
        done.notify()
    while not stop.is_set(): 
        sleep(1)
```

the results are quite different:

```
Available before A (MiB): 7626.12109375
Press Enter...
Available before Process (MiB): 5571.82421875
Press Enter...
134247509.654
Available with Process (MiB): 3518.453125
Press Enter...
```

---

The for-loop does indeed require more memory after each iteration, but that's obvious: it stacks the `total_results` from the mapping, so it has to allocate space for a new array to hold both the old results and the new and free the now unused array of old results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should know the difference between `thread` and `process` in `Operating System`. see this [What is the difference between a process and a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread).

In the for loop, there are `processes`, not `threads`. Threads share the address space of the process that created it; processes have their own address space.

You can print the process id, type `os.getpid()`.

Comment: It's not so black and white, as I pointed out. Processes may share physical memory, though they have their own address spaces.