# Getting name of the running application with java

Tags: java

i think the title explain the probleme, in fact, if i had a **host** and a **port** of running application how we can determine there name with java.

```
public String getApplicationName(String host,int port) {//some code}
```

Comment: Is not clear what you are asking. Generally to an host and port answer an application server that can handle many different wars or ears (if it is a java application server). There is not name for that.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma this question has nothing to do with the name of current executing method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I jumped to conclusion in my comment earlier. I guess getting the process list from the command may be useful. Again OS specific...

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -e");
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); //
//Run you pattern matcher here to parse data - host & port etc.
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> host and a port of running application

Only operation system is aware of applications that are running now. So it's impossible to get info about processes avoiding writing `OS specific` logic.

E.g for `Windows` it looks like:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("tasklist.exe");
InputStream procOutput = proc.getInputStream ();
if (0 == proc.waitFor ()) {
    // TODO scan the procOutput for your data
}
```

Comment: the application is running in the JVM, is it possible to get the main class at least ?

Comment: @user3237201, `jvm` is running inside the process managed by `OS`. 2 different applications run 2 different processes. It doesn't matter `jvm` or not processes are completely encapsulated, until you doesn't talk about `Threads` inside the same application. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread