# JavaScript's execution VS application context in a threaded language?

Tags: javascript, applicationcontext, executioncontext

I'm trying to visualize what threads are in terms of implementation in memory. I don't have a com-sci background, so I apologize for any fundamental understanding errors (please point out such errors).

My understanding of a process is a 'boxed' area in memory that includes several 'sub'-boxed threads. Here is a helpful SO answer that I've seen: [What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread) on this.

I know that a JavaScript process only encompasses a single thread, but that you still have these 'boxed' memory spaces - i.e. an execution context that encapsulates some memory able to access parent scope.

My understanding of, for example, an `application context` passed to an Android activity, is that it is a 'snapshot' of the process's memory environment (I would imagine ALL the thread and SOME of the process) so that the process can recreate the thread in a new box.

If the above is correct, would it be correct to say that conceptually speaking, a JavaScript execution context and an application context in a threaded language context are comparable in that they both refer to a memory space that is an environment for further work.

Comment: No, closures are a completely different thing than threads. They are merely a data structure in the memory space, not a box themselves.

Comment: Are all `execution context`s in JavaScript implemented by closure?

Comment: No, an "execution context" is a *stack frame*. I think were confusing that with closures, the "*encapsulat[ion] to access parent scope*".