# What are the disadvantages of threads over process?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

*-Interview Question*

I was asked the disadvantages of `thread`. And what are the scenario where we shouldn't use `thread` instead use `process`?

I couldn't think much except *invalid memory access* in some case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between  a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/200469/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite this post contain only positive points of thread.

Comment: Threads do have a lot of advantages.  It is just that a lot of programmers don't know how to write threaded code correctly.  Deadlock and race bugs are very hard to diagnose and fix.  Much less of a problem with a single-threaded process, it isolates memory so a thread in another process can't corrupt anything.  That isolation also makes it hard to get processes to co-operate however, doing something about that tends to cause bugs that are very hard to diagnose and fix.

Comment: @HansPassant __Process__ too suffer deadlock and race condition.

Comment: That's something you can say if you don't want to get hired.  Just beef-up on this stuff, it is important.

Comment: that is a clever move, i guess then

Answer (score 1):

Threads, spawned by the same process, all share the same memory. Processes all run in their own memory context.

In Linux (I don't know what the behavior under Windows is like) a newly spawned child process will usually received a copy of certain part the parent process' memory context an therefore is more expensive memory-wise at runtime and CPU-time/MMU wise at creation. Also context switching - (off)loading the process from or to the CPU (this happens, when a process or thread has nothing to do and is pushed to a queue in favor of processes or threads with actual work) - might be more expensive with a process.

On the other hand processes might be much more secure since their memory is isolated from the memory of their sibling processes.