# Is fork() + exec() the only way to execute a process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

In Windows, you can execute a process using [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now I want to know how to execute a process in Linux, so far I only found that you can do that by calling `fork()` and then calling `exec()`.

Is this the only way to execute a process in Linux?

Comment: How many ways do you need?

Comment: `fork()` is the only way to create a new process in Linux. If you call, for example, `system()`, it will call `fork()` on your behalf. Are you saying that don't want your code to call `fork()` directly, or are you saying that you don't want your code to call `fork()` at all, even indirectly, through library calls?

Comment: Well, `clone()` is a separate syscall IIRC...

Comment: *sigh*. You are right, of course. Also, `vfork()` exists. I miss the simplicity of v7 UNIX.

Comment: If you want an API more like `CreateProcess`, there is [`posix_spawn`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn), but it, too, just calls fork and execve for you.

Comment: Bottom line: there are library functions like `posix_spawn` and `system` for your convenience, but at the syscall level the `fork`+`exec` paradigm remains.

Comment: also, system, popen,

Comment: The basic mechanism for creating a new "thread of execution" in Linux is `fork()/exec()`.  There are many different APIs and library functions that let you do different things on top of this basic mechanism.  ALSO: please note that the differences between `process`, `thread` and `LWP` might be less than you might expect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread

Answer (score 2):

Linux provides both high-level and low-level interfaces for starting new processes.

### Low-level interfaces

The primary low-level interface is the one you have already discovered: `fork()`.  This is often followed quickly by one of the several `exec()` functions, but an `exec()` is unneeded if it is satisfactory for the new process to execute the same code as the original.  That's more common than it may sound to someone more used to the Windows API.

POSIX also defines `posix_spawn()` family, which serve as special-purpose alternatives to `fork()` + `exec()` for certain circumstances to which the latter are not well suited.  `posix_spawn()` is implemented on Linux via the `clone()` library function (see next).

Although they are not in POSIX, Linux also provides `clone()` and `vfork()` as alternatives to `fork()`.  On modern Linux these use the same system system call that `fork()` does, but not the `fork()` library function itself.  There's not much reason to use `vfork()` any longer -- it is perhaps indicative that POSIX used to have it, but removed it nearly a decade ago.  Linux-specific `clone()`, on the other hand, has some interesting behaviors that are occasionally useful.  It provides a more general interface to the fork system call than any of the other functions discussed here do, but it is not portable.  Generally speaking, prefer `fork()` unless you need something it cannot provide.

## High(er)-level interfaces

Linux provides some higher-level interfaces as well.  The primary two are `system()`, which executes a shell command and waits for it to complete, and `popen()`, which launches a shell command with either its standard input or standard output connected to a pipe, by which the concurrently-running parent process can communicate with it.  Both of these are specified by POSIX, and on POSIX systems they are specified to operate via `fork()` + `exec()`.  Of course Windows has `system()`, too, and `_popen()`, but not `fork()` or any direct analog.

## Summary

Overall, then, a userspace Linux process can start a new process only by forking, but that is to be distinguished from calling the `fork()` library function, even indirectly.  There are at least six different C library functions in GNU / Linux that can serve as an interface for starting a new process.  Some of those interfaces furthermore permit the new process to execute the same code (a copy of the process image of the original) indefinitely, which is sometimes a useful thing to do.  It is the `fork()` part of `fork()` + `exec()` that starts a new process; the `exec()` part merely changes what code the new process runs.

Comment: I agree that `vfork()` is nasty, but it was once a part of the SUS — Single Unix Specification — which was 'POSIX + …'.  For example, see: POSIX 2004 [`vfork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html) where it is marked 'obsolescent'.  It was removed from POSIX 2008, the current version.  Like `gets()` still exists even though it is no longer standard, `vfork()` still exists even though it is no longer standard.

Comment: `vfork` is still valuable for performance reasons, particularly when the program that needs to fork+exec has a lot of runtime-writable data. The cost of setting the entire address space copy-on-write for regular `fork`, and then reverting that again on `exec`, is substantial.