# ElectronJS app to load plugins as separate processes

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building an ElectronJS desktop app that will look similar to the image below with a sidebar of tools to click on and a right panel to load them into.

I want each tool to be a **plugin** so I can easily create/add/remove tools from the app

When clicking a tool in the sidebar it will load the plugins settings and files and run functions to build the content on the right.

Ass some plugins will be large apps I do not want to load them all and bogg down memory.

Is there a way to load each plugin tool in the right panel as its own process and then terminate the process and release memory used by that plugin once a new plugin tool is clicked on and loaded into the content panel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a worker with [electron-worker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-workers) and use it whenever you click on one of the tabs.

You can create a new [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) with the `show` option to `false`. It will then act as a **new process**.
*Link to the article*

You can use the [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) to contact the [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to then **fork a plugin**.
See [Node.js fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

*Useful electron [article](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2)*

See [Multithreading in electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading) if performance is a issue.

FYI [Differences between process and a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)