# What is the difference between CPU core's thread and any software's application thread?

Tags: multithreading, web-applications, cpu-registers, hyperthreading, cpu-cores

I have a web application which supports multi threading in which we can run `async` tasks simultaneously on different thread. I understood what that thread mean.

Now suppose the server on which the application is running has multiple cores CPU with hyper threading enabled.

Now, how my application is supposed to take advantage of these threads. Is there any relation between these two which I am missing.

What i understand from CPU's threads is that

> *A thread is a single line of commands that are getting processed, each application has at least one thread, most have multiples. A core is the physical hardware that works on the thread. In general a processor can only work on one thread per core, CPUs with hyper threading can work on up to two threads per core.
>   For processors with hyper threading, there are extra registers and execution units in the core so it can store the state of two threads and work on them both, normally to change threads you have to empty the registers into the cache, write that back to the main memory, then load up the cache with the new values and load up the registers, context switches hurt performance significantly.*

But when you have too much backgrounds tasks running, how they are utilizing just limited number of core's threads (i.e. 2 to 8).

PS: I have already checked [What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread) and not looking for definition of process. So its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making use of multiple cores in your program, then the os will schedule which cores run which threads and will take many factors into account, including other processes running, what exactly your code is trying to do, and much more. In regards to `async` tasks, these may not necessarily be running on a different thread or core, they may be tasks that are not instantaneous, so some scheduler may decide to start doing other things until there is a signal that the `async` task is complete. It will vary widely depending on the language you are programming the web application in, and the implementation.