# Does the OS create a new thread for each application process?

Tags: android, multithreading

When reading [Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) on threads and processes. The documentation is too ambiguous they say that it runs under a single thread called `main` but not sure whether it's single threaded per process or across processes.

I'm trying to understand the thread creation in my phone. I just created two sample apps and tried to print the current `thread id` and `thread name` using `Thread.currentThread().getId()` and `Thread.currentThread().getName` in both the apps the thread name was `main` and the `thread id` is `2`. Similarly I tried printing process id for individual app with `android.os.Process.myPid()` - the `process id` were different. So it's obvious that it's creating new process for each application.

I'm doubtful whether it's the same thread used for rendering the activity between Application1 and Application2. If yes, how this is handled by Android framework? If it's a single thread for the entire device (phone) then what happens when I invoke `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000 * 60 * 60)` in one application and try to launch another activity from Application2 from `adb` shell command. Will this cause any exception here?

Is there any thread pool associated with a process - in the case of Android when it creates a new process for an Application?

As per my understanding, `zygote` process is cloned during each application process is getting created (the parent process would be zygote)? Is `zygote` creating a main thread which all the applications are reusing?

How does process and threads are associated with each other? Can parent and child process share the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are sub-object of processes.

Each process can have one or more threads, and each has it's own memory space.

[image]

Threads on different processes are different threads.

You can read more about the differences between them here:
[What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)

Comment: Then why do they really have the same thread id even when i kill and run the app multiple times?

Comment: @rm-rfstar Once you start a new process, it gets loaded into a new environment. It's thread count start from 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

> When an application component starts and the application does not have
>   any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux
>   process for the application with a single thread of execution. By
>   default, all components of the same application run in the same
>   process and thread (called the "main" thread).

This and more on this topic can be found in the official documantation here: [Android processes and threads overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

From myself I can add, that same application components share the same process and main thread, unless they are especially registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` to run in a separate process. Nevertheless, when a new process is started, Android will create and start few threads, one of which is the main/UI thread, it will have same id - 2, since it's the 3rd to be started by the system.

Comment: I'm little confused with the last line. Since it's the 3rd to be started by the system why does it hold the id 2? And what are first two threads?

Comment: @rm-rfstar thread count starts from 0, so if it's 2, it's basically 3rd in the row. Sometimes, it might be 1, meaning that it's 2nd.. What are the others I do not know, but I might guess they are responsible for some service backup work or error handling (showing ANR window, etc.)