# Handling a thread crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, thread-safety, threadpool

I have searched online for the following question: **Can a process continue execution if one of its spawned threads crashes in cpp?**

All answers seem to suggest that its not possible/can lead to undefined behaviour (even after writing sigsegv handler) since threads share memory; or there are some specific platforms on which one can handle a thread crash making your code platform specific.

Edit: I want to know -

- if I can handle unhandled exceptions thrown by a thread
- if can I handle a general crash (the most probable answer for this being no)

So my questions are:

Say I have a main process which spawns 'n' threads. Each of those threads don't want to communicate with each other; however they want to communicate with the main process.

1. If I make data structures shared between threads and my main process **read-only**; can I handle a thread crash safely in this case without any potential UB?
2. What I am worried about is, that even if those threads don't want to communicate with each other, there is still a chance that a thread may try to access memory of some other thread (say a bug in code), since threads share the same address space. How should I go about handling this case then?
3. I am fine in making my code platform specific (I am restricting myself to cpp though). What platforms support handling a thread crash?
4. Is memory corruption due to a thread crash the only thing I should worry about while handling a thread crash? Say, I guarantee that a thread will always access its own memory and will never access memory of some other thread. Can I safely handle a crash for this thread? Is there any documentation or guarantees given by cpp on when can I safely handle a thread crash?

**Note:** I know that I wouldn't need to worry about invalid memory access had I been using processes; but I don't want to use processes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For #1, you can't make those data structures "read-only" in a way that would prevent #2 which is a very real possibility. For #4, no corruption is not the only problem. If something "crashes" in a non-terminal way, such as throwing an exception that somehow causes the thread to abort without bringing down the whole process, then objects and resources may be left in an undeterministic state. This is distinct from corruption. Generally, if a thread properly crashes, it _will_ crash the entire process. You might try to prevent that with a catch-all for _some_ exceptions, but that's problematic.

Comment: If you really need something to run in isolation and not affect the main process, consider an out-of-process solution. That is, you essentially spawn a child process and use IPC to sync data with it. If that process crashes, it won't affect the parent process for the most part, depending on how the communication / data sharing is implemented.

Comment: "Can a process continue execution if one of its spawned threads crashes in cpp?" No.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: Wouldn't this depend on the OS? Coz each OS kernel can handle access to restricted memory regions differently. Maybe popular OS like Linux or Windows, do it by killing the spawning process, but that shouldn't mean every OS should do the same. Or should they?

Comment: Ask yourself how would you feel about a program continuing after one of its parts failed? I would get very nervous because you never know what other damage has been done. So even if a program would continue I would do everything I could to fail hard and fast so I can at least get a crashdump and some debug info out of the situation.  So NO you cannot handle crashes safely, you can handle exceptions safely but you need to design and code for it.

Comment: What kind of crash are you talking about? Can you actually constrain this to specific types of crashes?

Comment: The worst thing you can do is to continue executing your code with unhandled errors as if nothing happens, only to run into issues hours later. That kind of code is kind of totally unmaintainable/fixable because probably none of the problems you see will be reproducible.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Good question that. Maybe OP is mixing unhandled exceptions with actual crashes (e.g. invalid memory access, use after free problems etc.)

Comment: Exactly, we don't know. Maybe OP doesn't know the differences either, which makes this mostly guesswork. +1 on the advise to use a separate process to sandbox the crashing code and to allow recovering from it crashing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry about that...I am new to using threads. I would want to know about both - unhandled exceptions and an actual crash

Comment: @kiner_shah If we go by the definitions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread (which match with other definitions I have seen), then the answer in the general case is a firm NO. IF a process is a shared memory space, then it is by definition not possible to have any confidence about the state of the shared space once one thread in that space crashes - because that thread could have crashed because it was writing randomly in the shared space and finally hit something that caused a fault. Processes are isolated, threads are not.

Comment: @Frodyne, makes complete sense. I am just thinking what if the OS guarantees proper state of shared memory in case of any faults? Something like, fault occurred -> rollback changes? Something transaction-like? If my question doesn't make sense, please feel free to ignore this though :-)

Comment: Neither C++ nor the OS would unroll changes to memory. It would be expensive to build, cost extra memory and runtime resources. So no there is no protection. In the end as a developer you have a responsibility here, either prevent memory invalidations by design or build recovery mechanisms by hand. And even than there are many unrecoverable scenarios when your code has UB (like crashing threads)

Comment: Your question in the end is not even about threads. The basic question is still : will my program be in a valid state after unhandled errors or invalid memory access. Also whenever you have code that can catch OS exceptions (like invalid memory access) and you catch that with (...) and continue... you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Write your code such as the thread won't crash is the only thing to do. If the thread is to throw some exceptions, you have to handle them (i.e. either from the thread itself or "propagate" them to the main thread to handle them afterwards, using a pointer to exception).

Comment: @Fareanor If you want to handle the exception from the "main" thread, I would consider using std::async, and use std::future get to rethrow the exception on the mainthread.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Exactly ! I remember I used to do it with `std::packaged_task` for instance (but it does the `std::exception_ptr` shenanigans for us under the hood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are a lot of system level stuff that is shared, can cause crashes if not handled properly. File handlers, memory allocators and other stuff.

If you want to keep going you need to handle the cause of the crash. Exceptions would be an example (rollback the state until you get to a known good one).

You can't always do this. If for example you are running some library you don't control you don't know what they do in there.
For this you can create a new process. Sending data back and forth is more cumbersome but it gives you enough isolation so that one process can crash without breaking the other one.